# In how many bits do I fit

Tags: code-golf, binary

For any positive 32-bit integer (`1 ≤ n ≤ 0xFFFFFFFF`) output the number of bits needed to represent that integer.

## Test cases

```
| n    | n in binary | bits needed |
|----------------------------------|
| 1    | 1           | 1           |
| 2    | 10          | 2           |
| 3    | 11          | 2           |
| 4    | 100         | 3           |
| 7    | 111         | 3           |
| 8    | 1000        | 4           |
| 15   | 1111        | 4           |
| 16   | 10000       | 5           |
| 128  | 10000000    | 8           |
| 341  | 101010101   | 9           |

4294967295 => 11111111111111111111111111111111 => 32
```

So `f(16)` would print or return `5`

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: This is the ceiling of the base-2 logarithm.

Comment: @orlp It actually is `floor(log2(num))+1`

Comment: @KritixiLithos Right.

Comment: @KritixiLithos What's an example for when `ceil(log2(num)) != floor(log2(num)) + 1`? I'm racking my brain trying to figure out why the distinction is important.

Comment: Nevermind, just realized that the distinct is important when `num` is a power of two.

Comment: This is a trivial challenge with a lot of trivial solutions. There are however some non-trivial solutions too. To voters: Please read the [first sentence of this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/how-can-we-help-users-who-are-put-off-by-the-use-of-golfing-languages/10132#10132) before upvoting builtin functions. (humbly taken from this [comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103822/output-the-sign#comment252501_103822))

Comment: Am I wrong that you need 32 bits to represent any 32-bit integer? If I want to represent 1 in binary, I need 31 0's and one 1. I can't store "11" as "11" in memory.

Comment: @MatthewRock Technically, you could store `1` in one bit (`1`). With fixed-width integers, yes, that would take up 32 bits (assuming 32-bit word size), but 31 of those bits are redundant (leading zeroes).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how many bits does it take to store zero (0)?

Comment: @Octopus 1 bit.

Comment: @BrianJ But this: `ceil(log2(num+1)) == floor(log2(num)) + 1`

Comment: [For 64 bit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35177/base-2-integer-logarithm-of-64-bit-unsigned-integer?rq=1) (without the +1).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
bg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@5@U/v@/sZEpAA)

Comment: Esoteric language won again... `bg`

Comment: @devRicher I expect to be beaten by a 1 byte solution still, to be honest.

Comment: At least this answer gets it's upvotes; it's not in the `bg`.

Comment: `bg` in gaming means `bad game` :)

Comment: @yoyoyonny or battleground haha.

Comment: Or (and I may be dating myself a little) Blood-Gulch (halo 3) lol.

Answer (score 35):

## JavaScript (ES6), 18 bytes

```js
f=n=>n&&1+f(n>>>1)
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 step=1 value=8 oninput="O.value=f(this.value)">
<input id=O value=4 disabled>
```

Comment: This is one of the few non-trivial solution here. Nice tactic!

Comment: Should it be `n>>>1` to support `n > 0x7FFFFFFF`?

Comment: @Arnauld Hmm, didn't know `>>` failed on `n` that high. Thanks.

Comment: Nice, my first attempt was `f=(a,b=1)=>a>1?f(a>>1,++b):b`

Answer (score 28):

## x86 Assembly, 4 bytes

Assuming Constant in `EBX`:

```
bsr eax,ebx
inc eax
```

EAX contains the number of bits necessary for Constant.

Bytes: `☼¢├@`

Hexadecimal: `['0xf', '0xbd', '0xc3', '0x40']`

Comment: Could you please include a hexdump of the actual 8 byte compiled x86 Assembly code?

Comment: Did so. And thank you, because I realized I made a mistake. I added an "inc eax" to fit the rules. I lost a byte. :(

Comment: Oh wow you changed my post to proper formatting. Thanks for correcting it!

Comment: By the way, [Assembly submissions can assume that the input is already stored in a specific register](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8508/34543), so I think you could shave off a few bytes that way.

Comment: Oh that's nice! Well, then it's down to four!

Comment: Is it customary to count assembly submissions as the number of bytes of the compiled machine code rather than the assembly language source code?

Answer (score 18):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 14 bytes

```python
int.bit_length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#DctLCoAgFEbhca3iJxAUboFpD4JaSRCEWULcIty/OfgGZ3A8ZqwpcGz2ELf74DNeyT8fGIGhCS3BECxhIIwE3WV91uYwVk9l8X55l5UwDvUC4SoISCZ4yUqp9AM)

Comment: It works in Python 2, too.

Comment: It does indeed. Forgot Python 2‘s *int* was 64 bits wide, not 32 bits.

Comment: Python 3's `bit_length` is `bit_length()`.

Comment: @dfernan This is not a function call; it's a function. If **n** is an *int*, `int.bit_length(n)` and `n.bit_length()` do exactly the same.

Comment: @Dennis, understood. In that case, your answer is not entirely correct and should depict an additional three bytes.

Comment: @dfernan I'm sorry, but I don't understand which three bytes you're talking about.

Comment: I was referring to `(n)` from `int.bit_length(n)`, as `int.bit_length` by its own is not valid, working code.

Comment: @dfernan `int.bit_length(n)` is a function *call*, and thus a snippet that assumes the input is stored in a variable. This is *not* allowed by our rules, so appending `(n)` would make this answer invalid. However, `int.bit_length` evaluates to a function and can be saved in a variable for later use. [This is allowed by default.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7205/12012)

Comment: @Dennis, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: `n.bit_length()` is the way it would be used in the code e.g., `123 .bit_length()`. If [the assembly solution may assume that the input is in a registry](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104785/in-how-many-bits-do-i-fit/104828#comment254680_104828) then Python solution should be allowed to get the input from a variable too. Though if the question is to write a function then `int.bit_length` works too (`f=` is implied and `Class.method(instance)` is allowed in Python in addition to `instance.method()`).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I see your point, but [Assembly programs may take input from registers](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8508/12012) is an I/O rule that doesn't apply to all languages.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The comments of some random answer isn't the place to debate the rules that have been set down. If you disagree with the popular rulings, post your own answer on the relevant meta question, with clearly explained reasoning, including how you think it'll make things better (which, incidentally, can't just be "makes golfing easier"). If people agree (i.e. upvote), then bam! Rules changed. That can't happen if you just discuss it in comments.

Answer (score 15):

### Mathematica, 9 bytes

```
BitLength
```

Alternatively:

```
Floor@Log2@#+1&
#~IntegerLength~2&
```

Answer (score 15):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
 ?
_:
2/#(!@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/labyrinth#@69gzxVvxWWkr6yh6PD/v6EZAA)

#### Explanation

The program simply repeatedly divides the input by 2 until it's zero. The number of steps are kept track of by duplicating the value at each step. Once it's reduced to zero we print the stack depth (minus 1).

The program starts at the `?` which reads the input. The main loop is then the 2x2 block below, going counter-clockwise:

```
:   Duplicate current value.
_2  Push 2.
/   Divide.
```

Once the value is zero after a full iteration, the linear bit at the end is executed:

```
#   Push stack depth.
(   Decrement.
!   Print.
@   Terminate.
```

Comment: This solution is complete - it takes input and provides the answer, and does not utilise any existing function for this specific purpose - it calculates the answer manually.  To me this is more in the spirit of the game than most other answers.

Answer (score 15):

## C, 31 bytes

```c
f(long n){return n?1+f(n/2):0;}
```

... Then I thought about recursion. From obscure to obvious, and with one fourth of the length dropped off.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5b6517d8f479be3)

---

## <s>C, 43 bytes</s>

```c
c;
#define f(v)({for(c=0;v>=1l<<c;++c);c;})
```

Calling `f` with an **unsigned** value (e.g. `f(42u)`) will "return" its bit length. Even works for `0u` !

**Ungolfed and explained:** (backslashes omitted)

```c
c;
#define f(v)
    ({ // GCC statement-expression

        // Increment c until (1 << c) >= v, i.e
        // that's enough bits to contain v.
        // Note the `l` to force long
        // arithmetic that won't overflow.
        for(c = 0; v >= 1l << c; ++c)
            ; // Empty for body

        c; // Return value
    })
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26c71114f72b0815)

Comment: OP guarantees n>=1, so `n?...:0` is not necessary.

Comment: @MadPhysicist well I do have to stop the recursion somewhere, don't I ;)

Comment: OIC. Didn't read carefully, feel like a dumbass now. Neat answer either way.

Comment: @MadPhysicist no worries, thank you very much :)

Comment: For the non-recursive solution assuming gcc statement expressions, I reckon you might have been inclined to use the `#define f(n) ({64-__builtin_clzl(n);})` approach as well.

Comment: @Moreaki yep. For some reason I was sure that the builtin would be too long -- but now [Digital Trauma](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104871/30000) has pretty much nailed it that way.

Answer (score 14):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 7 bytes

```perl6
*.msb+1
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#HcrZBoBAGAbQ@@8pvoukhfjbSb3KaJmIFhrFSM8@0bk@l9G8y2RsgM3SH49Js3VRspkhFtdgPk6uy65NEPIBaXpLT7Ht@NfYU3idIEWGHBVqSAEpIWmNLBd8)

### Explanation:

[`*`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/WhateverCode) makes it become a WhateverCode lambda, and indicates where to put the input

[`.msb`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/msb) on an Int returns the index of the most significant bit (0 based)

`+1` is combined into the lambda, and adds one to the eventual result of calling `.msb`.

Answer (score 13):

## C preprocessor macro (with gcc extensions), 26

```bash
#define f 32-__builtin_clz
```

Uses GCC's [count-leading-zeros builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fclz-4353).

Call this as a function, e.g. `f(100)`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#ZY7rboJAEIX/8xQnGhNWt60ueCHYvoglhMKik9DF7C79oeHZ6WAvMXGSSebM5cw3JVM2XaWxd76i9vn0NkwrXZPRqBGppzz/6KjxZPKyuQxkPD4LMgjHqrDHUqI8FRbzOYsvgWsAjnFIaXCrm9Yc4bXzZeG0O2R4xRUrCSURScQSW4mdxGrNueFULKKYF2KVxMlmq5I1@l@vurX8mR2WKQh7OLrotg7/3QVeHnqHZSZ4e7H4gxvjbBmxDiezppKYVe9mIu8YKZO4d6BMiPR22/9wWO07a5gi6Idv).

Comment: Oh wow, I thought about using a builtin but dropped the idea because I thought it was going to be too long... Well played.

Comment: Lucky the OP specified n >= 1 :D

Answer (score 12):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <strike>56</strike> 37 bytes

**This solution works with all the required input values.**

The biggest problem Retina faces in this challenge is the fact that its strings have a maximum length of 2^30 characters, so the usual way of dealing with numbers (unary representation) doesn't work with values greater than 2^30.

In order to solve this problem I adopted a different approach, keeping a sort of decimal representation of numbers, but where each digit is written in unary (I'll call this representation *digitunary*). For example the number `341` would be written as `111#1111#1#` in digitunary. With this representation we can now work with numbers of up to `2^30/10` digits (~ a hundred million digits). It is less practical than standard unary for arbitrary arithmetic, but with a bit of effort we could do any kind of operations.

> NOTE: digitunary in theory could use any other base (e.g. binary `110` would be `1#1##` in base 2 digitunary), but since Retina has builtins to convert between decimal and unary and no direct way to deal with other bases, decimal is probably the most manageable base.

The algorithm I used is making successive integer divisions by two until we reach zero, the number of divisions we made is the number of bits needed to represent this number.

So, how do we divide by two in digitunary? Here's the Retina snippet that does it:

```
(1*)(1?)\1#        We divide one digit, the first group captures the result, the second group captures the remainder
$1#$2$2$2$2$2      The result is put in place of the old number, the remainder passes to the next digit (so it is multiplied by 10) and is divided by two there -> 5 times the remainder goes to the next digit
```

This replacement is enough to divide a digitunary number by 2, we just need to remove possible .5s from the end if the original number was odd.

So, here's the full code, we keep dividing by two until there are still digits in the number, and put a literal `n` in front of the string at each iteration: the number of `n` at the end is the result.

```
.                  |
$*1#               Convert to digitunary
{`^(.*1)           Loop:|
n$1                    add an 'n'
(1*)(1?)\1#            |
$1#$2$2$2$2$2          divide by 2
)`#1*$                 |
#                      erase leftovers
n                  Return the number of 'n's in the string
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6/HpaJlqMxVnRCnoadlqMmVp2LIpWGopalhaK8ZA5RQMVRWMYJBLs0EZUMtFS5lrrz//02MLE0szcyNLE0B)

---

**Updated solution, 37 bytes**

Big refactoring with many good ideas that golfed about a third of the length, all thanks to Martin Ender!

The main idea is to use `_` as our unary symbol: in this way we can use regular digits in our string, as long as we convert them back to `_`s when it is needed: this lets us save many bytes on division and on insertion of multiple digits.

Here's the code:

```
<empty line>    |
#               put a # before each digit and at the end of the string 
{`\d            Loop:|
$*_                 Replace each digit with the corrisponding number of _
1`_                 |
n_                  Add an 'n' before the first _
__                  |
1                   Division by 2 (two _s become a 1)
_#                  |
#5                  Wherever there is a remainder, add 5 to the next digit
}`5$                |
                    Remove the final 5 you get when you divide odd numbers
n               Return the number of 'n's in the string
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@8@lzFWdEJPCpaIVz2WYEM@VF88VD2RxxStzKZty1SaYqnBx5f3/b2JkaWJpZm5kaQoA)

Comment: I've used a similar numeric form (but called it *Unary-Coded Decimal*), which is pretty handy for arithmetic with Sed.

Answer (score 11):

## Ruby, <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
->n{"%b"%n=~/$/}
```

Thanks Jordan for golfing off 3 bytes

Comment: You can save a byte with `%`: `->n{("%b"%n).size}`.

Comment: Wait, this is shorter: `->n{"%b"%n=~/$/}`.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript ES6, 19 bytes

```
a=>32-Math.clz32(a)
```

[`Math.clz32`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/clz32) returns the number of leading zero bits in the 32-bit binary representation of a number. So to get the amount of bits needed, all we need to do is substract that number from 32

```js
f=
  a=>32-Math.clz32(a)
```

```css
pre {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<input id=x type="number" oninput="y.innerHTML = f(x.value)" value=128><br>
<pre>Bits needed: <pre id=y>8</pre></pre>
```

Comment: The alternative `a=>1+Math.log2(a)|0` is also 19 bytes.

Comment: @Neil `1+...|0` screams *minus tilde*! `a=>-~Math.log2(a)` is 18

Comment: @edc65 I count 17... but yes, I was sure I was missing something, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Neil Feel free to post it as a seperate answer. It uses a different method than my answer so it would feel unfair to use yours for a reduced byte count

Answer (score 10):

## Jolf, 2 bytes

```
lB
```

Just convert to binary and then find the length.

Answer (score 10):

## [Julia 0.4](http://julialang.org/), 14 bytes

```julia
!n=log2(2n)÷1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia#Dce7CYAwFAXQWqe4CkICzyKJv0ZxEMuoCHKV4G4O4GAxxSlOLDie126Vpf5eE7crgDgIZQRW4ASNoBcMAtMmXWJTXGN0ns13OPhsqqycRz2h8gtLAQUFdb7Sxx8)

Comment: Much more interesting than the other answers. +1

Answer (score 10):

## bash / Unix tools, 16 bytes

```
dc<<<2o$1n|wc -c
```

Save this in a script, and pass the input as an argument. The number of bits required to represent that number in binary will be printed.

Here's an explanation:

dc is a stack-based calculator.  Its input, parsed into tokens, is:

2 — Push 2 on the stack.

o — Pop a value off the stack (which is 2) and make it the output base (so output is now in binary).

The value of the argument to the bash program ($1) — Push that argument on the stack.

n — Pop a value off the stack (which is the input number) and print it (in binary, because that's the output base) with no trailing newline.

So the dc command prints the number in binary.

The output of dc is piped to the command wc with the -c option, which prints the number of characters in its input.

The end result is to print the number of digits in the binary representation of the argument.

Comment: Nice choice of language, but it would be even cooler if you included an explanation.

Comment: @NH Thanks.  I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 9):

## Google Sheets, 15 Bytes

Takes input from cell `A1` and outputs to the cell that holds the formula

```vba
=Len(Dec2Bin(A1
```

or

```vba
=Int(1+Log(A1,2
```

or

```vba
=Int(Log(2*A1,2
```

## Excel, 17 Bytes

Same as above but formatted for MS Excel

```vba
=Len(Dec2Bin(A1))
```

or

```vba
=Int(1+Log(A1,2))
```

or

```vba
=Int(Log(2*A1,2))
```

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
l.B
```

[Test suite available here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l.B&input=3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A7%0A8%0A15%0A16%0A128%0A341&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
l.BQ    Q is implicitly appended
   Q    eval(input)
 .B     convert Q to binary string
l       len(.B(Q))
```

Comment: Alternatively: `hsl` or `.El`, in which `l` computes the log base 2, and `hs` or `.E` compute ceiling.

Answer (score 8):

## Jelly, 2 bytes

```
BL
```

Converts to binary, finds length.

Answer (score 8):

## C#, <s>63</s> <s>45</s> 31 bytes

Saved 18 bytes, thanks to Loovjo, and TuukkaX

Saved 14 bytes, thanks to Grax

```
 b=>1+(int)System.Math.Log(b,2);
```

It uses, that a decimal number n has ⌊log2(n)⌋+1 bits, which is described on [this](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-bits-in-a-decimal-integer/) page:

> ### Number of Bits in a Specific Decimal Integer
>
> A positive integer n has b bits when 2^(b-1) ≤ n ≤ 2^b – 1. For example:
>
> - 29 has 5 bits because 16 ≤ 29 ≤ 31, or 2^4 ≤ 29 ≤ 2^5 – 1
> - 123 has 7 bits
>   because 64 ≤ 123 ≤ 127, or 2^6 ≤ 123 ≤ 2^7 – 1
> - 967 has 10 bits because
>   512 ≤ 967 ≤ 1023, or 2^9 ≤ 967 ≤ 2^10 – 1
>
> For larger numbers, you could
> consult a table of powers of two to find the consecutive powers that
> contain your number.
>
> To see why this works, think of the binary representations of the
> integers 2^4 through 2^5 – 1, for example. They are 10000 through 11111,
> all possible 5-bit values.
>
> ### Using Logarithms
>
> The above method can be stated another way: the number of bits is the
> exponent of the smallest power of two greater than your number. You
> can state that mathematically as:
>
> bspec = ⌊log2(n)⌋ + 1
>
> That formula has three parts:
>
> - log2(n) means the logarithm in base 2 of n, which is the exponent to
>   which 2 is raised to get n. For example, log2(123) ≈ 6.9425145. The
>   presence of a fractional part means n is between powers of two.
> - ⌊x⌋ is the floor of x, which is the integer part of x. For example,
>   ⌊6.9425145⌋ = 6. You can think of ⌊log2(n)⌋ as the exponent of the
>   highest power of two in the binary representation of n.
> - +1 takes the exponent to the next higher power of two. You can think of this step as accounting for the 2^0th place of your binary number,
>   which then gives you its total number of bits. For our example, that’s
>   6 + 1 = 7. You might be tempted to use the ceiling function — ⌈x⌉,
>   which is the smallest integer greater than or equal to x — to compute
>   the number of bits as such:
>
> bspec = ⌈log2(n)⌉
>
> However, this fails when n is a power of two.

Comment: You have an extra space in there `...)+ 1)...` -> `...)+1...`. Also, I think you can return the value directly instead of printing it.

Comment: You can drop it down to 31 by doing `b=>1+(int)System.Math.Log(b,2);`  The int conversion provides the same output as Math.Floor and you don't need the using statement if you only reference System once.

Answer (score 5):

## C#, 32 bytes

```
n=>Convert.ToString(n,2).Length;
```

Converts the parameter to a binary string and returns the length of the string.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 20 bytes

```hs
succ.floor.logBase 2
```

Composes a function that takes logarithm base 2, floors, and adds 1.

Answer (score 4):

## [Befunge-93](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), <s>23</s> 21 Bytes

```
&>2# /# :_1>+#<\#1_.@
```

Befunge is a 2D grid-based language (although I'm only using one line).

```
&                      take integer input
 >2# /# :_             until the top of the stack is zero, halve and duplicate it
          1>+#<\#1_    find the length of the stack
                   .@  output that length as an integer and terminate the program
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@69mZ6SsoK@sYBVvaKetbBOjbBiv5/D/v7GJIQA)

Comment: @JamesHolderness Thanks, I figured it could be shortened since it had so many hash/spaces, but I couldn't quite get it.

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X005xiZeRdlKT1nfQdkoRtvw/39jE0MA "Befunge-93 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 4 bytes

```
p#bi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jellyfish#@1@gnJT5/7@hGQA)

Print (`p`), the length (`#`) of the binary representation (`b`) of the input (`i`).

Answer (score 3):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 5 bytes

```
ri2b,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UaZSk8/@/oRkA)

Read input (`r`), convert to integer (`i`), get binary representation (`2b`), get length (`,`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 19 bytes

```matlab
@(x)ceil(log2(x+1))
```

Anonymous function that adds 1, computes binary logarithm and rounds up.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gUaGZnJqZo5GTn26kUaFtqKn5P03BViExr9iaK03DUFNHIU3DCEwag0kTMGkOJi3ApKEphDKDUEYQUWMTQ83/AA)

Comment: Well, [I tried](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107134/31516) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 18 bytes

```
:{~2^q>a|_Xq\q=q+1
```

That's incredible Mike! But how does it work?

```
:        Read input as integer 'a'
{        Start an infinite DO-LOOP
~2^q>a   If 2 to the power of q (which is 1 by default) is greater than a
|_Xq     Then quit, printing q
\q=q+1   Else, increment q
[LOOP is closed implicitly by QBIC]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>34</s> 27 bytes

For once, Java has some useful builtins! Now, we just need some shorter names...

```java
x->x.toString(x,2).length()
```

[**Try it online!**](https://repl.it/FC9D)

Of course, you can do this without builtins ([see Snowman's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105035/60919)), but for a higher byte count.

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 19 bytes

```
@(x)nnz(dec2bin(x))    % or
@(x)nnz(de2bi(x)+1)    % or
@(x)nnz(de2bi(x)<2)    % or
@(x)numel(de2bi(x))    % or
@(x)rows(de2bi(x'))
```

Octave has two functions for converting decimal numbers to binary numbers.

**`dec2bin`** converts a number into a string of the characters `1` and `0` (ASCII-values `48` and `49`). The length of the string will be equal to the necessary number of bits, unless specified otherwise. Since the characters `1` and `0` are non-zero, we can use `nnz` to find the number of elements like this: `@(x)nnz(dec2bin(x))`. This is 19 bytes, so it's tied with [Luis Mendo's other Octave answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104801/31516).

**Can we do better using `de2bi`?**

**`de2bi`** is a function that returns the binary numbers as a vector with the numbers `1` and `0` as integers, not characters. `de2bi` is obviously two bytes shorter than `dec2bin`, but we can no longer use `nnz`. We *can* use `nnz` if we either add `1` to all elements, or makes it into a logical vector with only `true` values. `@(x)nnz(de2bi(x)+1)` and `@(x)nnz(de2bi(x)<2)` are both 19 bytes. Using `numel` will also give us 19 bytes, `@(x)numel(de2bi(x))`.

`rows` is one byte shorter than `numel`, but `de2bi` returns a horizontal vector, so it must be transposed. `@(x)rows(de2bi(x)')` just so happens to be 19 bytes too.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 3 bytes

```
b2l
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=b2l&input=12)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina),  <s>44</s>  23 bytes

Requires too much memory to run for large input values. Converts to unary, then repeatedly divides by 2, counting how many times until it hits zero. Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
.*
$*
+`^(1+)1?\1
$1_
.
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@nxaWixaWdEKdhqK1paB9jyKViGM@l9/@/saUhAA)

Comment: I'm not sure this is valid. This isn't a case of "it requires more memory than you'll probably have" but "it requires more memory than Retina itself can handle". In particular, the initial conversion to unary will fail for inputs of order 2^30 and above, due to limitations in Retina's implementation.

Comment: If it is valid, it could be shortened a lot though: https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@nxaWixaWdEKdhqK1paB9jyKViGM@l9/@/saUhAA

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 21 bytes

#### 21 bytes, (ab)use the fact that `$=` must be an integer

```
say$==1+log(<>)/log 2
```

#### 25 bytes, naïve implementation

```
say length sprintf"%b",<>
```

#### <strike>28</strike> 23 byte version without whitespaces

```
$-++while$_>>=1;say++$-
```

```
1while($i//=<>)>=1<<++$_;say
```

---

**Usage**

```
$ echo 128 | perl -E '$-++while$_>>=1;say++$-'
8
$ echo 128 | perl -E 'say length sprintf"%b",<>'
8
```

Comment: Nice use of forcing the cast, but I think you can use `0|` or `$-=` instead of `$#_=` for -1 byte!

Comment: @DomHastings yes, you're right. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 28 Bytes

`def f(a):print len(bin(a))-2`

Comment: `lambda a:len(bin(a))-2`

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 17 bytes

```js
f=
a=>-~Math.log2(a)
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><div>Bits: <span id=o>
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @edc65.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 21 bytes

```
<?=-~log($argv[1],2);
```

- `log(x,2)` Computes log2(x)
- `~` is the binary negation operator that also cast to int
- `-` take opposite

#### 28 bytes

```
<?=strlen(decbin($argv[1]));
```

- `decbin` convert to binary
- `strlen` takes length

#### 28 bytes

```
<?=floor(log($argv[1],2))+1;
```

- `log(x,2)` compute log2(x)
- `floor ... +1` takes floor plus 1

#### 32 bytes (Thanks Titus)

```
for(;2**++$i<=$argv[1];);echo$i;
```

- `2**$n` compute 2^n ie. pow(2,n) until superior to $argv[1]

Comment: It would appear you no longer need the `log(x,2)` or `floor ... +1` explanations

Comment: OK, seems like a display bug (see my edit)

Comment: Your looping solution fails for powers of 2 (1,2,4,8 etc.); fix with `<=` instead of `<`. And `for(;2**++$i<=$argv[1];);echo$i;` is two bytes shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <strike>43</strike> 41

```java
v->{int b=0;for(;v>0;++b,v/=2);return b;}
```

Counts the bits the old fashioned way and returns the count. Lambda fits into a `LongFunction<Integer>`.

Comment: I always forget that lambda syntax is so forgiving, when Java in general is more rigid.

Comment: I've linked your answer in mine, as I feel guilty for just cheating with builtins :)

Comment: @FlipTack don't feel guilty, built-ins are not cheating (unless specified otherwise). Our answers are separate solutions so they are not duplicates either.

Comment: Do you not need `class {void main() {}...}` for Java answers?

Comment: @ericw31415 unless otherwise specified, a "program or function" is allowed, and output may be to standard output or a return value. This allows non-golfing languages to be a bit more competitive because we can use functional interfaces (lambdas).

Comment: @Snowman Java doesn't really have functions though, right? Aren't they all methods of a class? If the class isn't defined, the method couldn't exist.

Comment: @ericw31415 yes, Java has functions and yes, they must all be scoped to a class - either `static`, or belonging to an object with an implicit `this` pointer (similar to member functions in C++). Functions in the context of a lambda are a single function belonging to an implicit anonymous (compiler-generated) class that implements a functional interface. In other words, you are correct, but Java has syntactic sugar to make lambdas appear like first-class functions.

Comment: @ericw31415 lambda expressions, functional literals, etc. are all allowed. only if the post specifies "full program" must you include the boilerplate (and the default is "programs or functions")

Comment: Hello from the future! Increment `b` (or halve `v`) in the loop body to save 1 byte!

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

```
├l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@/9oypyc//8NzQA)

Explanation:

```
├l
├   binary representation (without leading zeroes)
 l  length
```

Since Actually uses arbitrary-width integers, this will work for any input, so long as there is enough memory and time.

Answer (score 2):

#### [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/), 2 bytes

```
¢l
```

`¢` converts the input into a base-2 string

`l` returns the length

Thanks ETHproductions for shaving off 3 bytes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! `¢` is a shortcut for `Us2)` (see the Unicode Shortcuts section of the docs), which allows you to just do `¢l` for 2 bytes. (I should add an implicit `U` at the beginning of every program...)

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 6 bytes

`1+⌊2⍟⍵`

Omega is the right argument, which is replaced with the number in question.

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/)

Comment: As it is, this would require curly brackets to make it a function. However, you can make it a function train with `⌊1+2⍟⊢`. ([link](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%20%u2190%20%u230A1+2%u235F%u22A2%20%u22C4%20f%201%202%203%204%207%208%2015%2016%20128%20341&run))

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 16 bytes

```
n->endof(bin(n))
```

Anonymous function.

Comment: `endof` is shorter than `length`.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>47</s> 39 bytes

```
int L(uint32_t X){return X?1+L(X/2):0;}
```

Not using a library function. The algorithm counts the number of bits needed by  shifting right (or the equivalent divide by 2) until 0.

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 4 Bytes.

```
~2BL
```

### Explained

```
~2BL    #
~        # Zero Space Segment, The rest of this code is interpreted as if it were a bunch of characters separated by spaces.
 2B     # Convert implicit input to Base 2
   L    # Get the length of that, and implicitly output.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn#@19n5OTz//9/Q2MA)

Comment: "ZSS" is not an explanation of ~ to anyone who didn't already know.

Comment: Sorry, Added a bit of detail.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 3 bytes

Alternative 3 byte answer. Takes `floor(log2(n))+1`

```
hsl
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hsl&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A7%0A8%0A15%0A16%0A128%0A341%0A4294967295&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

### awk, 32 bytes

Iterate 2's exponent and see when it's greater than given value. Return the value in `exit`:

```
{for(;++i<=32;)if(2^i>$0)exit i}
```

Run it:

```
$ echo 4294967295| awk '{for(;++i<=32;)if(2^i>$0)exit i}'
$ echo $?
32
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 27 bytes

```
f(n){return n?1+f(n/2u):0;}
```

Inspired by the [answer by Quentin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104846/25315). Uses an unsigned literal to avoid overflow when using 32-bit integers. Might be able to cut the unsigned part if `int` is 64-bit, but it's more interesting this way.

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, 21 Bytes

```
c=@(x)nnz(dec2bin(x))
```

Yay for anonymous functions!

Example usage:

```
c(6)

ans = 

     3
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 15 bytes

```julia
n->ndigits(n,2)
```

This is an anonymous function that wraps Julia's built-in `ndigits` function that counts the number of digits of the input in the given base. Here we're giving it a base of 2.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#Dcc9CoQwAETh3lMMgpDAWORnd20UD2IZI2nGJev9s3nwFa/lVfOmVK7y/Izobct3hVAE4whPBCISH2Ih3Kt7d75PiM4O6O3fWvRkM04hYd4wpUMjISIbWTucSu0P)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 11 bytes

```
2&(1+<.@^.)
```

This is a monadic verb that accepts input on the right.

```
2&(    @^.)  NB. Base 2 logarithm of the input
     <.      NB. Floor
   1+        NB. Add 1
```

Could likely be improved using `#` (tally) and `#:` (binary representation) but I haven't figured that part out yet.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulYKSmYahto@cQp6f5vyS1uAQkZqhgpGCsYKJgrmChYGiqYGimYGhkoWBsYsiVmpyRr6DumVdQWqIO4YD0QIX9S0sQ4mlgmf8A)

Comment: It's just `#@#:`

Answer (score 1):

## ForceLang, 88 bytes

Noncompeting, requires the latest interpreter release, which postdates the question. (The `ln` implementation used previously was too inaccurate with large values)

```
set i math.ln io.readnum()
set j math.ln 2
set k math.floor i.mult j.pow -1
io.write k+1
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 30 bytes

```
 #N::((length(to-string N 2)))
```

Pretty simple. Convert the number to binary (`to-string N 2`) and return the length of the string.

[Try it online!](https://andrakis.github.io/lithp-webide/?code=KAogICAgKGRlZiB4ICNOOjooKGxlbmd0aCh0by1zdHJpbmcgTiAyKSkpKQogICAgKHByaW50ICh4IDE2KSkgICAlIFJlc3VsdDogNQop)

### Alternate entry (no binary builtin), 38 bytes

```
 #N::((if(!= 0 N)((+ 1(x(>> N 1))))0))
```

[Try it online!](https://andrakis.github.io/lithp-webide/?code=KAogICAgKGRlZiB4ICNOOjooKGlmKCE9IDAgTikoKCsgMSh4KD4+IE4gMSkpKSkwKSkpCiAgICAocHJpbnQgKHggMTYpKSAgICUgUmVzdWx0OiA1Cik=)

Recursively shifts right by 1 each time the function is called, until we get to 0. This is an unsigned shift, so can support the full range of 0x0 - 0xFFFFFFFF. The Lithp `>>` operator is equivalent to Javascript's `>>>` operator.

Answer (score 1):

### Powershell, <s>66</s> 48 bytes

*-18 bytes thanks to @briantist*

```
function l {[math]::floor([math]::log($args[0])/[math]::log(2))+1}
```

```
($m=[math])::floor(m::log($args[0])/m::log(2))+1
```

Doing anything in Powershell is complicated, but it's better than Batch! In just Batch, this challenge isn't even possible (no decimal numbers=no logarithms).

Comment: Our respective PowerShell solutions use different methods, but yours can still be shortened by getting rid of `function l { }` because it's completely superfluous for the challenges here; `$args[0]` counts for args passed to the script itself. You could also do `($m=[math])::log($args[0])` and then replace the other 2 instances of `[math]` with `$m`, like `$m::floor`.

Answer (score 1):

### VBScript, 45 bytes

```
Sub l(n)
WScript.Echo Log(n)/Log(2)+1
End Sub
```

See result by adding `l(whatever the number is)` to the end of the file. Run with `cscript.exe` if you want the result in a command window.

Comment: You may consider adding a `<!-- language-all: lang-vbs -->` flag to this and all of your future VBS answers, so that they may have syntax highlighting

Comment: @TaylorScott Thanks, I'll consider doing that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), 19 bytes

```perl
$_=0|1+(log)/log 2
```

The score includes **1 byte** for the `-p` switch the program requires.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#U4mxVYrJU7JWUFYITi1RyC8tKSgtUShOLUgsSizJL1IoyVfISy3PycxLVUgDcVOLgbKlmSWpev9V4m0Nagy1NXLy0zX1gYSC0f//hlxGXMZcJlzmXBZchqZchmZchkYWXMYmhv91CwA)

Comment: Some mad golfing skills here... just when I thought there was no more room for improvement in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Javascript, 23 bytes

```
x=>x.toString(2).length
```

```js
f=x=>x.toString(2).length
document.write(f(341)) // 9
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 8 bytes

```
1+int(logBASE(Ans,2
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>39</s> 36 bytes

```c
f(n,*p){*p=0;while(n){n/=2;(*p)++;}}
```

Ungolfed version:

```c
 void f(long int n, int *p)
 {
   *p=0;
    while(n!=0)
    {
      n/=2;
     (*p)++;  
    }   
  }
```

The `main()` function that accepts number from `stdin`, would look like this:

```c
   int main()
   {
       int b=0
       long int num;
       scanf("%ld",&num);
       f(num,&b);
       printf("%d\n",b);
       return 0;
   }
`
```

### Alternative:

```c
f(long n){i=0;while(n!=0){n/=2;i++;}return i;}
```

Ungolfed version:

```c
int f(int n)
{
  int i=0;

  while(n!=0)
  {
    n/=2;
    i++;

  }
   return i;
}
```

Comment: You can shave off some bytes by removing "n!=0" since n evaluates as true if nonzero.

Comment: This is also invalid, won't compile.
This, however, will. `p;f(n){p=0;while(n)n/=2,++p;}` works with only 29 bytes.
`p;f(n){for(p=0;n;n/=2)++p;}` works with only 27.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 20 bytes

```
INPUT N?LEN(BIN$(N))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 19 bytes

```
->i{i.to_s(2).size}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 39 bytes

```
lambda x:__import__('math').frexp(x)[1]
```

Not even kind of the shortest, but it showcases a neat function that could be useful elsewhere!

`frexp(n)` represents n as `n = m * 2**e` with `0.5 <= abs(m) < 1` and then returns the tuple `(m, e)` as output. For positive integers, `e` is exactly the number of bits required to represent the number.

Comment: You could save a few bytes by just using `import`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 39 bytes

```lisp
(defun f(i)(length(format nil "~B" i)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc07DoAgEEXR3lVMrGZKET@07sQo6CSIRrF162hlhvIkN@9Nnq8jJZytuwM4ZEJvwxJXdPu5jRECeyifoQQmooTHySGig4qo@KEkagkt0Un0ElWTqc2ksrTW2bVWRpu2U@ZbSC8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 22 bytes

```python
lambda n:len(bin(n))-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKic1TyMpM08jT1NT1@h/QVFmXolCmoaJkaWJpZm5kaWp5n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos), 60 bytes

```
	' S ' g
g
	S dab
	g S ' dab f
f
	f ' '
	S dab
'
	dip
S
	dot
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8lPyS/@/59TXSFYQV0hnSudizNYISUxiYszHSwCZCqkcaVxcaYBOeowSSAjJbOAKxhI5Zf8///f0BQA)

(`S` computes the sum, `S ' dab f` divides by 2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
bL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiYkwiLCIiLCIzNDEiXQ==)

#### Explained

```
bL
b  # binary
 L # length
```

Answer (score 0):

## 68020 assembler, <strike>2</strike> 4 bytes (I think)

```
BFFFO D0, D1
INC D1
```

The BFFFO instruction finds the position of the first set bit in parameter 1, and stores the result in parameter 2. I think it is a 2-byte instruction. Unfortunately, it is indexed from 0, not 1. Hence you need an INC on D1 afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 11 bytes

```
0{${h}2/;}#
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@29QrVKdUWukb12r/P//f0NTAA)

This works by continually doing `x = x // 2` until `x = 0`, and counting the number of divisions taken:

```
0            \ Push a 0 (initial counter)
 {$     ;    \ While input > 0:
   {h}       \  Increment counter
      2/     \  Floordiv input by 2
         }#  \ Output final counter
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) v3+, <s>37</s> 34 bytes

```powershell
param($n)(1..32|?{!($n-shr$_)})[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@QWJSYq6GSp6lhqKdnbFRjX60I5OkWZxSpxGvWakYbxP7//9/EyNLE0szcyNIUAA)

Comment: Taking input as `param($n)` is 3 bytes shorter -- `param($n)(1..32|?{!($n-shr$_)})[0]`

Comment: @TimmyD so it is! Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 32 bytes

```groovy
{Long.toBinaryString(it).size()}
```

This is an unnamed closure.

[Try it here !](http://ideone.com/lnngQC)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 4 bytes

```
#&#:
```

**Explanation:**

```
#      NB. Counts length of bit list
&      NB. Connects # and #:
#:     NB. Creates list of bits
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATL, 2 bytes

```
Bn
```

The shortest solution in MATL seems to be just direct, by measuring the length of the binary representation (as a vector).  Other options are `ZlkQ`, which takes the base-2 logarithm, floors it and adds 1, or `YBn` which converts the input to a binary string and finds the length.

Answer (score 0):

### [K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language))/[Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 4 bytes

```
#2\:
```

`\:` gets the representation of right-hand in base left-hand - in this case, base 2 of the input. `#` then just counts this

```
k)2\:341 
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
k)#2\:341
9
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), <s>19</s> 16 bytes, Thanks to @JoKing

```
&#\<_$.@j3:/2\+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XU46xiVfRc8gyttI3itE2/P/fzFgBAA)

19 bytes:

```
&0#;1+\2/:!3j@.$_\;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XM1C2NtSOMdK3UjTOctBTiY@x/v/fzFgBAA)

5 bytes shorter than Befunge-93 :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 70 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S S N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_PRINT][S S S T  S N
_Push_2][T  S T S _Integer_division][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT][S N
N
_Discard_top][T N
S T _Print_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIgYiTixMEuCACXJwgWkGBE8QCsTlBHDAJZAPlubggWkEczv//TYwsTSzNzI0sTQE) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer i = STDIN as integer
Integer r = 0
Start LOOP:
  if i is 0:
    Call function PRINT_AND_EXIT
  i = i integer-divided by 2
  r = r + 1
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

function PRINT_AND_EXIT:
  Print r as integer
  Exit with error
```

**Example run (`n=16`):**

```
Command   Explanation                 Stack       HEAP     STDIN   STDOUT  STDERR

SSSN      Push 0                      [0]
SNS       Duplicate top (0)           [0,0]
SNS       Duplicate top (0)           [0,0,0]
TNTT      Read STDIN as integer       [0,0]       {0:16}   16
TTT       Retrieve                    [0,16]      {0:16}
NSSN      Create Label_LOOP           [0,16]      {0:16}
 SNS      Duplicate top (16)          [0,16,16]   {0:16}
 NTSSN    If 0: Jump to Label_PRINT   [0,16]      {0:16}
 SSSTSN   Push 2                      [0,16,2]    {0:16}
 TSTS     Integer-divide (16/2)       [0,8]       {0:16}
 SNT      Swap top two                [8,0]       {0:16}
 SSSTN    Push 1                      [8,0,1]     {0:16}
 TSSS     Add (0+1)                   [8,1]       {0:16}
 SNT      Swap top two                [1,8]       {0:16}
 NSNN     Jump to Label_LOOP          [1,8]       {0:16}
 
 SNS      Duplicate top (8)           [1,8,8]     {0:16}
 NTSSN    If 0: Jump to Label_PRINT   [1,8]       {0:16}
 SSSTSN   Push 2                      [1,8,2]     {0:16}
 TSTS     Integer-divide (8/2)        [1,4]       {0:16}
 SNT      Swap top two                [4,1]       {0:16}
 SSSTN    Push 1                      [4,1,1]     {0:16}
 TSSS     Add (1+1)                   [4,2]       {0:16}
 SNT      Swap top two                [2,4]       {0:16}
 NSNN     Jump to Label_LOOP          [2,4]       {0:16}
 
 SNS      Duplicate top (4)           [2,4,4]     {0:16}
 NTSSN    If 0: Jump to Label_PRINT   [2,4]       {0:16}
 SSSTSN   Push 2                      [2,4,2]     {0:16}
 TSTS     Integer-divide (4/2)        [2,2]       {0:16}
 SNT      Swap top two                [2,2]       {0:16}
 SSSTN    Push 1                      [2,2,1]     {0:16}
 TSSS     Add (2+1)                   [2,3]       {0:16}
 SNT      Swap top two                [3,2]       {0:16}
 NSNN     Jump to Label_LOOP          [3,2]       {0:16}

 SNS      Duplicate top (2)           [3,2,2]     {0:16}
 NTSSN    If 0: Jump to Label_PRINT   [3,2]       {0:16}
 SSSTSN   Push 2                      [3,2,2]     {0:16}
 TSTS     Integer-divide (2/2)        [3,1]       {0:16}
 SNT      Swap top two                [1,3]       {0:16}
 SSSTN    Push 1                      [1,3,1]     {0:16}
 TSSS     Add (3+1)                   [1,4]       {0:16}
 SNT      Swap top two                [4,1]       {0:16}
 NSNN     Jump to Label_LOOP          [4,1]       {0:16}

 SNS      Duplicate top (1)           [4,1,1]     {0:16}
 NTSSN    If 0: Jump to Label_PRINT   [4,1]       {0:16}
 SSSTSN   Push 2                      [4,1,2]     {0:16}
 TSTS     Integer-divide (1/2)        [4,0]       {0:16}
 SNT      Swap top two                [0,4]       {0:16}
 SSSTN    Push 1                      [0,4,1]     {0:16}
 TSSS     Add (4+1)                   [0,5]       {0:16}
 SNT      Swap top two                [5,0]       {0:16}
 NSNN     Jump to Label_LOOP          [5,0]       {0:16}

 SNS      Duplicate top (0)           [5,0,0]     {0:16}
 NTSSN    If 0: Jump to Label_PRINT   [5,0]       {0:16}
NSSSN     Create Label_PRINT          [5,0]       {0:16}
 SNN      Discard top                 [5]         {0:16}
 TNST     Print as integer            []          {0:16}           5
                                                                            error
```

Program stops with an error: No exit found.

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 48 bytes

```
({<({<(({}[()]))>{()(<{}({}[()])>)}{}}{})>()}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6PaBoQ0qmujNTRjNTXtqjU0NWyqa2ECdpq11bVApGmnAWJp/v9vaGQBAA)

Readable version:

```
({< # Start a loop

  #devide by two:
  ({<(({}[()]))>{()(<{}({}[()])>)}{}}{})

>()} # Count interations
{} # pop the zero
) # push the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `L`, 1 byte

```
ḃ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0ko9S7IKlpSVpuhaLH-5oXlKclFwM5S9YbGxiCGECAA)

`ḃ` converts to binary; the `L` flag takes the length.