# A bit, a nibble or byte?

Tags: code-golf, number, binary

[Inspired by this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/104785/32686)

Given an integer in the range `0 <= n < 2**64`, output the minimum sized container it can fit in out of

- bit: 1
- nibble: 4
- byte: 8
- short: 16
- int: 32
- long: 64

### Testcases:

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 1
2 -> 4
15 -> 4
16 -> 8
123 -> 8
260 -> 16
131313 -> 32
34359750709 -> 64
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: This would be considerably easier if `2` was an output too...

Comment: @ETHproductions It would but alas, it isn't (it took me far to long to write an algorithm that did it)

Comment: I wish I understood the problem. ... wait, all it wants is the amount of bits needed to contain the number, rounded to the next fundamental structure?

Comment: @z0rberg's basically find the smallest container that the number will fit in out of the ones given.

Comment: Thanks! I realized it when I wrote the comment and edited it too late. I guess I need a rubber duck to talk to...

Comment: @Daniel the answers here take a completely different approach to the other question. When I say 'inspired by' it does not mean 'duplicate of'. No answers could be trivially modified to be valid for this question

Comment: AFAIK if it had all integers, the answer would be ceil(log2(n))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
bg.²îD1Q+o
```

### Explanation

```
bg         Push the length of the binary representation of input without leading zeros
  .²î      Push x = ceil(log2(length))
     D1Q+  Add 1 if x == 1 or add 0 otherwise
         o Push pow(2,x) and implicitly display it
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@5@Urndo0@F1LoaB2vn//xsBAA)

Answer (score 21):

### Python, 39 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:4**(n>1)*(n<16)or 2*f(n**.5)
```

Counts how many times one must take the square root for `n` to be below `16`, with some special-casing to avoid outputs of 2.

If 2 were included, we could do

```python
f=lambda n:n<2or 2*f(n**.5)
```

with True for 1.

---

**41 bytes:**

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:i*(2**i>n)or f(n,i<<1+i%2)
```

Repeatedly doubles the exponent `i` until `2**i>n`. Skips from `i=1` to `i=4` by shifting an additional bit when `i` is odd.

Alt 45 bytes:

```python
f=lambda n,i=4:4**(n>1)*(2**i>n)or 2*f(n,i*2)
```

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how you can come up with so many solutions for a problem. Basically as a programmer I have learned to find a solution to a problem and work with it until it works. Guess I still have a lot to learn about golf! Respect.

Comment: @xnor, how does your first answer output `1` when the square root of 0 or 1 is always 1 (infinite recursiveness in `or 2*f(n**.5)`)?

Comment: @dfernan I believe the part after the `or` is only evaluated if the part before evaluates to something falsy (zero). For n=0, and for n=1, `n>1` evaluates to `False`, which is treated as zero in a numeric expression, and `n<16` evaluates to `True`, which is treated as one in a numeric expression. So `4**(n>1)*(n<16)` is 1.

Comment: @trichoplax, that is right. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 12):

## J, 19 bytes

Monadic verb taking the number on the right and spitting out the container size. There are a couple of equivalent ways of writing it so I've included both.

```
2^2(>.+1=>.)@^.#@#:
2^s+1=s=.2>.@^.#@#:
```

Explained by explosion:

```
2^2(>.+1=>.)@^.#@#: NB. takes one argument on the right...
                 #: NB. write it in binary
               #@   NB. length (i.e. how many bits did that take?)
  2          ^.     NB. log base 2 of that
   (>.     )@       NB. ceiling
      +1=>.         NB. +1 if needed (since no container is two bits wide)
2^                  NB. base 2 exponential
```

What's cool is we see two different ways of taking log base 2 in J. The first is the obvious `2^.`, which is a numerical logarithm. The second is `#@#:`, which can be read as "length of base-2 representation". This is almost equivalent to one-plus-floor-of-log-base-2, except that `#:0` is the one-element list `0`, which is exactly what we want. This beats `1+2<.@^.1&>.` by 8 bytes.

In use at the REPL:

```
   f =: 2^2(>.+1=>.)@^.#@#:
   f 131313
32
   f 34359750709
64
   (,.f"0) 0 1 2 15 16 123 260
  0  1
  1  1
  2  4
 15  4
 16  8
123  8
260 16
```

---

Old, overly clever 20 byte solution.

```
2&^.(>.+1=>.&.)@#@#: NB. takes one argument on the right...
                #@#: NB. how many bits
2&^.                 NB. log base 2 of that
     >.              NB. ceiling
       +1=>.         NB. +1 if needed (since no container is two bits wide)
    (       &.)      NB. undo log base 2
```

Answer (score 9):

## Python, <strike>53</strike> <strike>50</strike> 49 bytes

```py
lambda n:[w for w in[1,4,8,16,32,64]if n<2**w][0]
```

Comment: `lambda n:[w for w in[1,4,8,16,32,64]if n<2**w][0]` is one byte shorter

Comment: Was just about to post something similar. +1

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, <s>44</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

Thanks @orlp for 5 bytes and @MartinEnder for 1 byte.

```
FirstCase[{1,4,8,16,32,64},x_/;2^x>#]&
```

Finds the first the elements in the list `{1, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64}` such that 2^number is greater than the input.

Answer (score 8):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 19 bytes

```
(a<2**_FI2**,7RM2i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@6@RaGOkpRXv5gkkdcyDfI0yNf///28EAA)

#### How it works

```
                     a is 1st cmdline arg, i is 0 (implicit)
         2**,7       Construct powers of 2 from 0 to 6 [1 2 4 8 16 32 64]
              RM2    Remove 2
       FI            Filter for elements for which:
 a<2**_                a is less than 2 to that element
(                i)  Get 0th item of resulting list and autoprint
```

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES7), 35 bytes

```
n=>[1,4,8,16,32,64].find(b=>2**b>n)
```

Comment: A recursive version such as `f=(n,b=1)=>2**b>n&&b-2?b:f(n,b*2)` should be slightly shorter.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>46</s> <s>43</s> 38 bytes

*Thanks to JungHwan Min and Martin Ender for saving 3 bytes!* *Thanks to ngenisis for a big 5-byte savings!*

```
2^⌈Log2@BitLength@#⌉/.{2->4,0->1}&
```

Unnamed function taking a nonnegative integer as input and returning a positive integer. `BitLength@#` computes the number of bits in the input, and then `2^⌈Log2@...⌉` computes the smallest power of 2 that's at least as large as the number of bits. Finally, `/.{2->4,0->1}` takes care of the special case that there's no "niblit" between bit and nybble, and also fixes the answer for the weird input `0`.

Comment: Save 3 bytes by using `BitLength@#` instead of `⌊1+Log2@#⌋`. Then instead of replacing `∞` with `1` you can replace `0`, saving another 2 bytes and you're tied for first.

Comment: This can actually be done entirely with `BitLength`. See [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105044/61980)

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 40 bytes

```julia
n->filter(x->n<big(2)^x,[1;2.^(2:6)])[1]
```

This is an anonymous function that generates an array of the powers of 2 from 0 to 6, excluding 2, and filters it to only those elements *x* such that 2<sup>*x*</sup> is greater than the input. The first such element is the answer. Unfortunately this requires promoting 2 to a `BigInt` to avoid overflow on *x* = 64.

This is actually quite similar to orlp's Python answer, though I didn't see it before concocting this approach.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#FYjbCoMwEETf/YpFELKwKbnUiL2E/ofVhxJTAmVbgg/@fRpnOAdmSryz9DF9tjWLXXq@vdJbGFx2mvTVnBZhLg5nnPRc4jcDQ2IQikATmOq@4irG1u2O3x4lsGfbj0OvBjViAzWPX068RdF2WgeQHrrw5JaACaJgxGblUP4)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 30 bytes

```
{first 1+<*>$_,1,4,8,16,32,64}
```

`+<` is Perl 6's left bit shift operator, which many other languages call `<<`.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 31 bytes

```haskell
f n=[2^i|i<-0:[2..],2^2^i>n]!!0
```

32-byte alt:

```haskell
f n|n<2=1|n<16=4|1>0=2*f(sqrt n)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 143 bytes.

```
int f(long a){a=Long.toBinaryString(a).length();if(a<2)return 1;if(a<5)return 4;if(a<9)return 8;if(a<17)return 16;if(a<33)return 32;return 64;}
```

Comment: I know I can make this shorter, Io do it when I'm at a computer.

Comment: save 50 bytes:  `return a<2?1:a<5?4:a<9?8:a<17?16:a<33?32:64;`

Comment: @Mindwin I know, but I'm traveling and won't have access to a computer for a while. I'll get around to it.

Comment: Does the score make it a... [love byte](https://www.google.com/search?q=143)?

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 43 bytes

```
f x=head$filter((>x).(2^))$[1,4,8,16,32,64]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>65</s> 55 bytes

This is a lambda expression which takes a `long` and returns an `int`. Never golfed in Java before, so this should be easily beatable:

```java
x->{int i=1;while(Math.pow(2,i)<=x)i<<=1+i%2;return i;}
```

[**Try it online!**](https://repl.it/EyLU/3)

---

For **47 bytes**, we could have:

```java
x->{int i=1;while(1L<<i<=x)i<<=1+i%2;return i;}
```

However, `1L<<i` overflows for return values larger than 32, so this fails for the final testcase.

Comment: This returns `4` when tested with `16` when it is supposed to return 8. Also you can still golf this solution by removing the brackets around `i<<=1+i%2;` since without `{}`s, the while loop will **only** execute the next line

Comment: @KritixiLithos should be fixed now - sorry, my Java's gone rusty...

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>39</s> 36 bytes

```
->n{2**[0,*2..6].find{|p|2**2**p>n}}
```

Thanks G B for helping golf

Comment: Should also work without parentheses. Also, the list could be 0,2,3,4,5,6 and using 1<<2**p.

Comment: ... because then you could use 0,*2..6.

Answer (score 2):

## bash, <s>49 bytes</s> 48 bytes

```
for((y=1;$[y==2|$1>=1<<y];$[y*=2])){ :;};echo $y
```

or

```
for((y=1;$[y==2|$1>=1<<y];)){ y=$[y*2];};echo $y
```

Save in a script and pass the number to be tested as an argument.

*Edit: Replaced || with |, which works because the arguments are always 0 or 1.*

**Note:** This works for integers up to the largest positive integer that your version of bash can handle. If I have time, I'll modify it to work up to 2^64-1 in versions of bash that use 32-bit signed arithmetic.

In the meantime, here's a 64-byte solution that works for arbitrarily large numbers (in any bash version):

```
for((x=`dc<<<2o$1n|wc -c`;$[x==2||x&(x-1)];$[x++])){ :;};echo $x
```

Answer (score 2):

### Racket 45 bytes

```
(findf(λ(x)(>(expt 2 x)m))'(1 4 8 16 32 64))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f m)
  (findf (λ (x) (> (expt 2 x) m))          ; find first function
         '(1 4 8 16 32 64)))
```

Other versions:

```
(define (f1 m)
  (for/last ((i '(1 4 8 16 32 64))         ; using for loop, taking last item
             #:final (> (expt 2 i) m))     ; no further loops if this is true
    i))
```

and using string length:

```
(define (f2 m)
  (for/last
      ((i '(1 4 8 16 32 64))
       #:final (<= (string-length
                    (number->string m 2))  ; convert number to binary string
                   i))
    i))
```

Testing:

```
(f 0)
(f 1)
(f 2)
(f 15)
(f 16)
(f 123)
(f 260)
(f 131313)
(f 34359750709)
```

Output:

```
1
1
4
4
8
8
16
32
64
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 30 bytes

```
2^(f=BitLength)[f@#-1]/. 2->4&
```

Explanation:

Let `N` be the set of nonnegative integers. Define two functions on `N`, `BitLength` and `NextPower` as follows:

```
BitLength(n) := min {x in N : 2^x - 1 >= n}
NextPower(n) := 2^(min {x in N : 2^x >= n})
```

This solution essentially calculates `NextPower(BitLength(n))` given an integer `n >= 0`. For `n > 0`, we can see that `NextPower(n) = 2^BitLength(n-1)`, so `NextPower(BitLength(n)) = 2^BitLength(BitLength(n)-1)`.

Now the Mathematica `BitLength` built-in agrees with the definition I gave for `n >= 0`. For `n < 0`, `BitLength[n] == BitLength[BitNot[n]] == BitLength[-1-n]`, so `BitLength[-1] == BitLength[0] == 0`. Thus we get the desired answer of `1` for `n==0`.

Since we skip straight from bit to nibble, we have to replace answers of `2` with `4`.

Comment: Nicely constructed! (Shame that the space is necessary.)

Answer (score 2):

## Stacked, <s>34</s> 30 bytes

```
@n 1 2 6|>2\^,:n 2 log>keep 0#
```

or

```
{!1 2 6|>2\^,:n 2 log>keep 0#}
```

The first takes input on the TOS and leaves output on TOS; the second is a function. [Try it here!](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/stacked/stacked.html)

### Explanation

```
@n 1 2 6|>2\^,:n 2 log>keep 0#
@n                               set TOS to `n`
   1 2 6|>2\^,                   equiv. [1, ...2 ** range(2, 6)]
              :                  duplicate it
               n                 push `n`
                 2 log           log base-2
                      >          element-wise `>`
                       keep      keep only truthy values
                            0#   yield the first element
```

Here's an example of it working [on the repl](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/stacked/repl.html):

```
> 8    (* input *)
(8)
> @n 1 2 6|>2\^,:n 2 log>keep 0#    (* function *)
(4)
>    (* output *)
(4)
```

### Test cases

```
> {!1 2 6|>2\^,:n 2 log>keep 0#} @:f
()
> (0 1 2 15 16 123 260 131313 34359750709) $f map
((1 1 4 4 8 8 16 32 64))
>
```

Or, as a full program:

```
{!1 2 6|>2\^,:n 2 log>keep 0#} @:f

(0 1 2 15 16 123 260 131313 34359750709) $f map

out
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 13 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 10.70 bytes

```
bL2AYZmD1=+2@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZrk3yMHCOjcl0MbbWNHCBiUKkFywyNQRDCAwA)

Port of Osable's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
bL2AYZmD1=+2@  # Implicit input
bL             # Length of binary representation
  2AY          # Log base 2 of above
     Zm        # Ceil of above
        1=     # Equals one?
       D  +    # If true, add one; else, pass
           2@  # Two to the power of above
               # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>49</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```
echo(2**ceil(log(log(1+$argn,2),2))-2?:2)+2;
```

Run like this:

```
echo 16 | php -R 'echo(2**ceil(log(log(1+$argv[1],2),2))-2?:2)+2;';echo
```

## Explanation

```
echo                       # Output the result of the expression
  (
    2**                    # 2 to the power
      ceil(log(            # The ceiling of the power of 2 of bitsize
        log(1+$argn,2),    # Number of bits needed
        2
      ))
      - 2 ?:               # Subtract 2 (will be added back again)
      2;                   # If that results in 0, result in 2 (+2=4).
  ) + 2                    # Add 2.
```

## Tweaks

- Saved 3 bytes by getting rid of the `$r=` assignment
- Saved 2 bytes by using `-R` to make `$argn` available

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, <s>40 36 31</s> 29 bytes

Simple anonymous function. It is assumed that the input value is an integer - see the caveat at the end.

```
@(a)(b=2.^[0 2:6])(a<2.^b)(1)
```

The code works as follows:

- First an array of the allowed bit lengths (1,4,8,16,32,64) is created and saved to `b`.
- Next we find the number of bits required to store the input number `a` by comparing with the maximum size of each container in `b` to see which are big enough.
- We then use the resulting index vector to extract the container size from `b` again.
- Finally we take the first element in the resulting array which will be the smallest container possible.

You can try it online [here](http://octave-online.net/).

Simply run the following code, and then do `ans(x)`.

---

The only caveat with this is that double precision is used for constants by default which means that it only works with numbers up to the highest value representable by a double precision float that is less than 2^64.

This can be fixed by ensuring that the number that is supplied to the function is an integer rather than a double. This can be achieved by calling the function for example with: `ans(uint64(x))`.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 18 bytes

```
2ri2b,2mLm]_({)}|#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@29UlGmUpGOU65MbG69RrVlbo/z/v6ExCAIA)

**Explanation**

```
2                   Push 2
 ri                 Read an integer from input
   2b,              Get the length of its binary representation
      2mLm]         Take the ceiling of the base-2 log of the length
           _(       Duplicate it and decrement it
             {)}|   Pop the top element, if it's 0, increment the next element
                     Effectively, if ceil(log2(input)) was 1, it's incremented to 2,
                     otherwise it stays the same.
                 #  Raise 2 to that power
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ʀ~‹E≬E?>c
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJ+IiwiIiwiyoB+4oC5ReKJrEU/PmMiLCIiLCIwIC0+IDFcbjEgLT4gMVxuMiAtPiA0XG4xNSAtPiA0XG4xNiAtPiA4XG4xMjMgLT4gOFxuMjYwIC0+IDE2XG4xMzEzMTMgLT4gMzJcbjM0MzU5NzUwNzA5IC0+IDY0Il0=)

This took a lot of experimenting to get to 9 bytes. Like at least 20 minutes of trying and trying.

### Explained

```
ʀ~‹E≬E?>c
ʀ          # The range [0, input]
 ~‹        # With 1 removed (filter by decrement, could also be 1o, but that's not as stylish)
   E       # with 2 raised to the power of each item. This creates a list of [1, 4, ...]
    ≬   c  # get the first item of that where
     E     #   2 to the power of the item
      ?>   #   is greater than the input
```

Comment: [8 with `M` flag](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBTSIsIiIsIn7igLlF4omsRT8+YyIsIiIsIjAgIy0+IDFcbjEgIy0+IDFcbjIgIy0+IDRcbjE1ICMtPiA0XG4xNiAjLT4gOFxuMTIzICMtPiA4XG4yNjAgIy0+IDE2XG4xMzEzMTMgIy0+IDMyXG4zNDM1OTc1MDcwOSAjLT4gNjQiXQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>71</s> 52 bytes

```
i;f(long long n){for(i=1;n>>i;i*=2);return i-2?i:4;}
```

Comment: Wouldn't an input of `(1<<15)+1` or more break this because of the signed behavior of `long long`? The type you really want is `uint64_t` which necessitates `#include <stdint.h>` which is *still* a loser compared to `unsigned long long`! Headers are the bane of golfing in c.

Comment: @dmckee I guess it could break it, but it seems to work at least on my computer. Haven't found an example which wouldn't work. I thought of using `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t`, but since it seems to work with `long long` I went with it.

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 27 bytes

```
:~a<2|_Xq]{~a<2^t|_Xt\t=t*2
```

Explanation

```
:        Get cmd line parameter N, call it 'a'
~a<2     IF 'a' is 0 or 1 (edge case)
|_Xq]    THEN quit, printing 1 ('q' is auto-initialised to 1). ']' is END-IF
{        DO - infinite loop
    2^t  't' is our current number of bits, QBIC sets t=4 at the start of the program.
         2^t gives the maximum number storable in t bytes.
 ~a<     IF the input fits within that number,
|_Xt     THEN quit printing this 't'
\t=t*2   ELSE jump to the next bracket (which are spaced a factor 2 apart, from 4 up)
         DO-loop is auto-closed by QBIC.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 13 bytes

```
7Zm@2-#2R^<)h
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=7Zm%402-%232R%5E%3C%29h&input=16&warnings=0)

```
7Zm@          -   [set_bit(0, i) for i in range(7)] <- create powers of 2
    2-        -  ^.remove(2)
      #    )h - filter(^, V)[0]
       2R^    -   2 ** i
          <   -  input < ^
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 43 bytes

```php
for(;1<<2**$i++<=$argn;);echo 2**$i-=$i!=2;
```

Run with `echo <number> | php -R '<code>'`.

loops `$i` up until `2**(2**$i)` is larger than input. (Tweak: `<<` instead of `**` to eliminate parens)
After the loop, $i is one too high; so it gets a decrement before calculating the output
- but not for `$i==2`.