# Find the number of leading zeroes in a 64-bit integer

Tags: code-golf, math, restricted-source, binary, bitwise

**Problem:**

Find the number of leading zeroes in a 64-bit signed integer

**Rules:**

- The input cannot be treated as string; it can be anything where math and bitwise operations drive the algorithm
- The output should be validated against the 64-bit signed integer representation of the number, regardless of language
- [Default code golf rules apply](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info)
- Shortest code in bytes wins

**Test cases:**

These tests assume two's complement signed integers. If your language/solution lacks or uses a different representation of signed integers, please call that out and provide additional test cases that may be relevant. I've included some test cases that address double precision, but please feel free to suggest any others that should be listed.

```
input                output   64-bit binary representation of input (2's complement)
-1                   0        1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
-9223372036854775808 0        1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
9223372036854775807  1        0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
4611686018427387903  2        0011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1224979098644774911  3        0001000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
9007199254740992     10       0000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
4503599627370496     11       0000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
4503599627370495     12       0000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
2147483648           32       0000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000
2147483647           33       0000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111
2                    62       0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
1                    63       0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0                    64       0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! What's the reason behind _"the input cannot be treated as string"_? This disqualifies all languages that can't handle 64-bit integers and is unlikely to lead to _more_ answers that take an integer, because this is the straightforward way when available anyway.

Comment: Can we return `False` instead of `0`?

Comment: @Arnauld There are already similar questions here and on other sites that specifically call for string-based solutions, but nothing that opens the question to math and logical operations. My hope is to see a bunch of different approaches to this problem that are not already answered elsewhere.  
Should this be opened to string solutions as well to be all-inclusive?

Comment: Several CPUs including x86 and ARM have specific instructions for this (x86 actually have several). I've always wondered why programming languages don't expose this feature since in most programming languages today you can't invoke assembly instructions.

Comment: It's 64 - [log2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104785/in-how-many-bits-do-i-fit).

Comment: @user202729 For positive input.

Comment: @Dave [Unobservable requirements are discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/10002#10002), although it's ok to simply encourage using methods you want.

Comment: @user202729 I think I worded this poorly: 'The output should be validated against the 64-bit signed integer representation of the number, regardless of language'

What I mean by that is that this question defines the number of zeros as the number of zeros in a 64-bit signed integer. I guess I made that constraint to eliminate signed vs unsigned integers.

Comment: @slebetman I thought that built-ins were excluded as part of the default code golf rules, but I just saw that it's only a suggested rule.

I assume changing the requirements at this point is poor form, but I'll remember that in the future!

Comment: The equation for this is 64 if 0, 0 if -ve and 63-floor(log2(n)) otherwise

Comment: [Don't "Do X without Y"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/46231)

Comment: @slebetman: many languages do have builtins for this, almost to the point where C and C++ are notable for their failure to portably expose modern CPU features like popcnt and bit-scan.  (Especially given their use-case of low-overhead highly-optimized code).  Most C compilers have their own incompatible and/or arch-specific intrinsics and builtins for this stuff.  Rust is fantastic; all the primitive integer types have popcnt, bit-scan, rotate, endian, saturating add/sub, and wrapping vs. overflow-checked vs. non-overflowing add/sub/mul/div etc. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html

Answer (score 42):

## x86_64 machine language on Linux, 6 bytes

```
0:       f3 48 0f bd c7          lzcnt  %rdi,%rax
5:       c3                      ret
```

Requires Haswell or K10 or higher processor with `lzcnt` instruction.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/19DK01TQ9NWKabCzTimwsQipsLALabCySWmwtkciI2VrLlyEzPzNDSruQqKMvNK0jSUVFNi8pR00jQMfTQ1rTFEDcCitf///0tOy0lML/6vW5VakZpcXJKYnA0A)

Comment: Builtins strike again /s

Comment: I recommend specifying the calling convention used (though you did say on Linux)

Comment: @qwr It looks like SysV calling convention because the parameter is passed in %rdi and it is returned in %rax.

Answer (score 25):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), <s>78</s> 70 bytes

```
2"1"\.}/{}A=<\?>(<$\*}[_(A\".{}."&.'\&=/.."!=\2'%<..(@.>._.\=\{}:"<><$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDkAwEAXQs5jQNha/WMq09BwmaSyEFVvSzNnrvet49/O5v1onGkmgvmgKLEt03EqvW3ZJCEVBBlZM8AA1QSbbMeBWRGRIkKIzceS21uEH)

Isn't this challenge too trivial for a practical language? ;)

<sub>side length 6. I can't fit it in a side length 5 hexagon.</sub>

#### Explanation

[image]

Comment: I laughed really hard at the "explanation". :D

Comment: I think you may have overcomplicated handling negative numbers/zero. I managed to fit a similar [program](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/18BCBwVNBSqFewV6riAHD0wtFJwUNADcmMUVIA8GwV1kCiXQp2CPlhaX8EILGADJKuhWrQgSkCUBlSoGmyGIpClBBWxA1kBNFpBDcxVAnHBLFsgVvz/38TM0NDMwszA0MLEyNzYwtzSwBgA) into side length 5 by not doing that hefty 2^64 calculation. It clearly isn't well golfed yet, though!

Comment: @fry Ah right, negative numbers always have 0 leading zeroes... which definitely leads to shorter program because generates 2^64 is long.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 31 bytes

```python
lambda n:67-len(bin(-n))&~n>>64
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYu7CsJAEEX7@YpUkhSBmdnZeQj6JTaKioG4BomIjb8etxO0uofDudNrvtwKL@fNbhn318Nx35S1Wj@eSnsYStuXrlu9y3arsjwvw3hqaD3dhzI353Yo02Nuu27pCfpgTskYk3oWs@zo8O8MRInUFcmFLbkFJiBmiUrhKrWTIIJANIrgehSsC5Ix5QitL0MJ/RUZmGrrScW/aMBAgB8)

The expresson is the bitwise `&` of two parts:

```python
67-len(bin(-n)) & ~n>>64
```

The `67-len(bin(-n))` gives the correct answer for non-negative inputs. It takes the bit length, and subtracts from 67, which is 3 more than 64 to compensate for the `-0b` prefix. The negation is a trick to adjust for `n==0` using that negating it doesn't produce a `-` sign in front.

The `& ~n>>64` makes the answer instead be `0` for negative `n`. When `n<0`, `~n>>64` equals 0 (on 64-bit integers), so and-ing with it gives `0`. When `n>=0`, the `~n>>64` evaluates to `-1`, and doing `&-1` has no effect.

---

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 36 bytes**

```python
f=lambda n:n>0and~-f(n/2)or(n==0)*64
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYtLasNAEAX3fQotpYBId09PfwzyXWQUIYEzFkYheOOry7MLxKtXFPW2x77cCh/HPFzH78s0NuVUzjiW6dnPbfnk7nZvyzBg96Fy/C7r9auh03Zfy97M7Vq2n73tuqMn6IM5JWNM6lnMsqPDuzMQJVJXJBe25BaYgJglKoWr1E6CCALRKILrUbAuSMaUI7S@DCX0v8jAVFtPKv6HBgwE@AI)

Arithmetical alternative.

Answer (score 11):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 14 bytes

```c
__builtin_clzl
```

Works fine on tio

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>35</s> 29 bytes

```c
f(long n){n=n<0?0:f(n-~n)+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIyc/L10hT7M6zzbPxsDewCpNI0@3Lk9T29C69n9uYmaehmZ1QVFmXkmahpJqioKSTpqGhaamNUIIJGIAFKn9DwA)

Than Dennis for 6 bytes

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler flags, 29 bytes by David Foerster

```c
-Df(n)=n?__builtin_clzl(n):64
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzLTsMwEADv@YpVEVJMG@RX/KAtXPgLqKLUIakl46A05QDi11mWXhBw2tHs7IZqCAEvYg7p1D3B5jh3Ke6vD7fFLxdHUogxz/Dcxlx@QzsNYQXh0E5wRfz6sGPFewHQjxOcgwhbEGsam3NLtFwyCgBeJtr35eKye8yLFfRlO4@pPD@JO8bYuvhArARWXkqlrOTKuFpbWzvu8L@zqI0QxhkunJZWOeu5QiGl9kTeGU2d9kKg59wK7yUdak4Tdc1V7b2hK8u1N39FjVJQ65TR7gctShTIP0Of2uGI1X1fZrbNd02zP8U0x9yE9JbI3Rj9BQ)

Comment: Worth noting that it's only for 64-bit machines (or any others with LP64/ILP64/etc. ABI)

Comment: Geez, that’s even shorter than any use of the [GCC built-in `__builtin_clzl`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fclzl) with which I can [come up](https://tio.run/##ZYzLTsMwEEX3@YpREZLdNsiv@EFa@BCootQhqSXjoJCyoOq3DyYbBKzu0Z1zx5eD93gTko/n7gV273MXw/Hu9FD86sKYK@xJHNMAiV7SPj02zfEc4hxS4@NnJInea1VfMaQZXtuQyDe00@C34E/tBOvMH08HWlwKgH6cYBEC7IHXOXaLm2mzoVkAeJvyvSer2@45rbbQk3YeI1mehAOltC6uiCXH0gkhpRFMalspYyrLLP7vDCrNubaacauEkdY4JpELoVwmZ7XKnnKco2PMcOdEHiqWE1XFZOWczivDlNN/iwoFz66VWtkfNCiQI/sC).

Comment: @Ruslan: good point, on systems where `long` is 32 bits (including Windows x64), you need `__builtin_clzll` (unsigned long long).  https://godbolt.org/z/MACCKf.  (Unlike Intel intrinsics, GNU C builtins are supported regardless of the operation being doable with one machine instruction.  On 32-bit x86, clzll compiles to a branch or cmov to do `lzcnt(low half)+32` or `lzcnt(high half)`.  Or `bsr` if `lzcnt` isn't available.

Comment: The test cases include "0" but `__builtin_clz(l)(l)` is undefined behavior for zero: [*"If x is 0, the result is undefined."*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fclz)

Comment: @MCCCS If it works, it counts. That's also why I keep the last answer

Answer (score 9):

## Java 8, <s>32</s> 26 bytes.

`Long::numberOfLeadingZeros`

Builtins FTW.

-6 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBboMwDIbP5Sl8BGlFCQSSlHXHSZO67dDbph1SGmg6CAhCu2rqs7Mg0Wpq8cX2b3@2k704iPl@@92rsq4aA3ub@51Rhb9OhdaySZy7Stbp1KhK@89jkDhO3W0KlUJaiLaFV6E0/DpgbdRbI4x1h0ptobRVd20apfPPLxBN3npj83@7zH5cVTp/gBdtZC6bJ8hg2Q/SYqG7ciOb92wlxdbO@pBN1fa3YxJnNhtfAu3ol6DlEUbVXZ9aI0tfac8@4xY/7lQhwR1JfyfaN/ljhv2uN3X1YIWtgrZbLpS@IskkMF5Qdcav7a@YQruZL@q6OLnam2DOznR27ucY5jwIwpAGKIxZRCiNGGJwr1EgMcYxixFmJKAhoxyFgIOAcBtxFhPbRzjGwBGimPPAggRZDyRCYcR5bCmKCI/hVokgwLaZhTFhw13XjNoYMKA/)

Comment: Ah, completely forgot about `numberOfLeadingZeros`.. You can golf it to 28 bytes btw: `n->n.numberOfLeadingZeros(n)`

Comment: Actually, `Long::numberOfLeadingZeros` is even shorter (26 bytes).

Comment: Wow, it doesn't happen very often that Java beats Python. Congrats!

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 25 bytes

Takes input as a BigInt literal.

```javascript
f=x=>x<0?0:x?f(x/2n)-1:64
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdFLbsIwEAbgfU@RZbJIMy@PZ1ApZ0GUVK2QgwBVuX3qBQjkQLzx5tP88/jd/m3Pu9PP8dKm4Ws/Tf16XH@OH7CB1bjp67Gj1LS4Upl2QzoPh/37Yfiu@7rFVM1e01RdV8FbQZ2IORKwWpAYg4Gl53QuY7pWxYKKIqopoAlFtujAN0oFRSLxDNxUclVxxBvlsgGAiO6U0wXyn@5jYdmsBODgrjk@grg@Wly24dGW7RLmcGMVS@Vq@aWNc1vORk8udrU6W9mCLevCgpXpHw)

Or [**24 bytes**](https://tio.run/##fdHNbsIwDAfw@56iJ9QeutqO49iTgGdBjE6bUIoATX37LgfQkAvNJZef/PfHz@53d9mfv0/XNg@fh2nq1@N6M27HDaxWfT12lJsWP4Sn/ZAvw/Hwfhy@6r5uMVez1zRV11Xw5qgRhZAIgmjklKKC5ud0LlO@VUVHWRBFBVCZUtBkEO6UHEUitgJMhUtVNsQ7Db4BgIRmVNIZyp//x0LfLEcI0UxKfAI2ebS4bOOj9e0SlnANwpr9asNLm@bWz0ZPLnazMlvZgvV1YcHy9Ac) by returning *false* instead of \$0\$.

Comment: Wouldn't `n=>n<1?0:n.toString(2)-64` perform the same?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I suppose you meant `n=>n<1?0:n.toString(2).length-64`, but that would not work anyway. [This would](https://tio.run/##fdHNTsMwDAfwO09Rbq1QO9txnBgxeAieYBpdGaoctFW8fslhE1M6mksuP/nvj6/dz@68Px2/p9bSRz8ftrNtX@0F3uBZuLVuSu/T6WhDTU039jZMn0@PNu@TndPYd2Ma6kPdolWL1zTVZlPBQ0GVyLlA4CR6DsFHiHafLmWwS1UsKAuiRAGMTMHFoOCulAqKRKwZaBTOVVkRr9SVDQAEVKWczpB/@xsLy2bZg/OqkuMDsMqtxXXrb23ZLmEOj044Wrla968NS1vORncudrGyWNmKLevCiuX5Fw), I think.

Comment: You're right. Thank you :( I though I found an alternative for you :/

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel No worries. :) It's indeed possible to have the `.toString()` approach working, but we still need a BigInt literal as input. Otherwise, we only have 52 bits of mantissa, [leading to invalid results when precision is lost](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP11Dw8TM0NDMwszA0MLEyNzYwtzSwDhPU68kP7ikKDMvXcNIU5OLkHpU5f//AwA).

Comment: The fact that the BigInt suffix is the same character as your parameter is very confusing...

Comment: @Neil Unreadable code on PPCG?? This can't be! Fixed! :p

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:-1<n<2**63and-~f(2*n|1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYtLasNAEAX3OcUsJdGC/k1/jHMYGSMscMbGeGMIuboyu0C8ekVR7/56Xm5N9n39vC5fp/NS2mGmYzvyNJks7Tz/rANP7ZvGfb09yla2VmaCOZlFnFEsqrrXwIB356BGZGFIoewSnihAzJqdMkx7p0kEieiUyf2o2Be0otRM6y9HTfsvKjD1NsQ0/tCBgQAPH6XcH1t7DuuwjeP@Cw)

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
0{[:I.1,~(64$2)#:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BCsJADEX3PUVQoRZqSTKZTFLoATyDuBKLuHHRpejVx9l0NsVVwvvk/TzzvEwDIIyAGd@X8TxQ/z2qHLjbj9fcNbsB2nkaWujhM8K8NM399njBDCeqmzOHkBiDWpSUoqGt2TZKayRKpKZIJpyCJcewRsQsXoCbSrkSp1rmiIncudgEy6y2iCG6a1ElFNc/PK6cqQgsqNiG1A@rvLZj/gE)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
1#.[:*/\0=(64$2)#:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xDsIwDEX3nsKiSKUIiu04jl2pJwEmRIVYGDpz9pClWSomW@/L7/ud52UaAGEEzNQO1/F4ueF0UNlz34733De7Abp5Gjo4wXeEeWma5@P1gRnOVDdnDiExBrUoKUVDW7NtlNZIlEhNkUw4BUuOYY2IWbwAN5VyJU61zBETuXOxCZZZbRFDdNeiSiiuf3hcOVMRWFCxDakfVnltx/wD)

### Explanation:

```
                #:  - convert 
                  ] - the input to
          (64$2)    - 64 binary digits
         =          - check if each digit equals 
        0           - zero
   [:*/\            - find the running product
1#.                 - sum
```

Comment: `1#.[:*/\1-_64{.#:` (17) is close but doesn't work for negative numbers :(

Comment: @Conor O'Brien Nice approach too!

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 18 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Jo King*

```perl6
64-(*%2**64*2).msb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rdNRb4IwEAfw936Ke9kEFL22x7WNWeb3mD7opomJzkWezLLPzi4bEzJIMOC9FNLml7s/5WN7PnBxvMDjDp6gYEqj5MEkCVNi4ukx3xRztTudITrs37d5DJ8KQE4v1nJ6@no6bqLZMn1evo1n8VzJXr6@wC5arF9wFU9GsM9hNBnLq16pryLV0Cz8e9ADS6XBGGudQcs@I@cyj77G47BSTd2Jeh1jaPfEWrNn1J6Ms94FtADmyg/0lTaGgqDBM0n3FLS0bisef/LpzQdEp0MwkgyhrGXkFV9Wv6@gKEObhcCSjEMKXF6YBt/P/89nv7xp8r0CUkZLKt4y@dq9t218W3WNVPGuztsbeezsvuWnBb61@67ZlG7l7V141ApbeboPj98)

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 22 bytes

```ruby
->n{/[^0]/=~"%064b"%n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY69CsJAEIR7n0ICKUP27/aniC8SYpEiZRDBQkRf/Ty8q9RqmB3mm73e1nvepjyc9sc4n2EZp1fXg8ra9fszX47bPOBy@GgQMRsBqycxSw5ek9/AaiCKqK6ALmTsFsA1QCKJYsNVSkMC20gAGEZQ4QgUbZwEnCK0QAwk9O811SthqTqr@JdvPzVk24MlvwE)

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: Another one that counts chars in a string‍♀️

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 56 bytes

<sup>Thanks [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for spotting a mistake!</sup>

```hs
f n|n<0=0|1>0=sum.fst.span(>0)$mapM(pure[1,0])[1..64]!!n
```

Might allocate quite a lot of memory, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxDoMgFIXhvU9xTTpgouQCKjQpvkGfgDAwaGoqhIhuvju1dPnOcP63S59pXXOeIZzhiRpPNqJOh6dz2mmKLpAR67t38UXisU2GNWhrwygdOltVIXu3BNDwC4DEbQk7nesbgIGWXdNA@@BcCMlRDKrvpOwVqnIMRV78p3hp8xc)

Maybe you want to test it with a smaller constant: [Try 8-bit!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hrybPxsDWoMbQzsC2uDRXL624RK@4IDFPw85AUyU3scBXo6C0KDXaUMcgVjPaUE/PIlZRMe9/bmJmnoKtAkheQaOgKDOvRC9Nk0tBIVpB1xhI6SjoGoIpAzAJYRuBSTOIiJE5kI79DwA)

### Explanation

Instead of using `mapM(pure[0,1])[1..64]` to convert the input to binary, we'll use `mapM(pure[1,0])[1..64]` which essentially generates the inverted strings \$\lbrace0,1\rbrace^{64}\$ in lexicographic order. So we can just sum the \$1\$s-prefix by using `sum.fst.span(>0)`.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
·bg65αsd*
```

I/O are both integers

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0PakdDPTcxuLU7T@/zcxMzQ0szAzMLQwMTI3tjC3NDAGAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ZYu7CQJREEXzqWLZUFyY35tPtImNuChiZLAgLBhbgJ0YmVuARdjI82WCRvdwOPc0b6fjvl7Oy9h37@ut68dlU5@P6WDldZ93q7quA8GQzCLOKBZF3UtgwL9zUCOyMKRQdglPFCBmzUYZpq3TJIJEdMrkdlRsC1pQSqa1l6Om/YoCTK0NMY0vOjAQ4Ac).

**Explanation:**

```python
·         # Double the (implicit) input
          #  i.e. -1 → -2
          #  i.e. 4503599627370496 → 9007199254740992
 b        # Convert it to binary
          #  i.e. -2 → "ÿ0"
          #  i.e. 9007199254740992 → 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  g       # Take its length
          #  i.e. "ÿ0" → 2
          #  i.e. 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 → 54
   65α    # Take the absolute different with 65
          #  i.e. 65 and 2 → 63
          #  i.e. 65 and 54 → 11
      s   # Swap to take the (implicit) input again
       d  # Check if it's non-negative (>= 0): 0 if negative; 1 if 0 or positive
          #  i.e. -1 → 0
          #  i.e. 4503599627370496 → 1
        * # Multiply them (and output implicitly)
          #  i.e. 63 and 0 → 0
          #  i.e. 11 and 1 → 11
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>10</s>  9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to a neat trick by Erik the Outgolfer (is-non-negative is now simply `AƑ`)

```
ḤBL65_×AƑ
```

A monadic Link accepting an integer (within range) which yields an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjiVOPmam8YenOx6b@P//fxNTA2NTS0szI3NjcwMTSzMA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##ddA7TgNBDAbg3qeIlHYi@TV@lEmdGyBERYNyAVoaaiouQJkDpF8p90guMhmxQgvLZhpL88m/bL88Hw6vrV1OX7u91afhc3v@aMP79e3Y2gNsqKwW3nqFsElmEWcUi6ruNTDKSP/Fy3cXgRqRhSGFskt4oozEQMya/SPDtHdpEo0kkIhOmdzTFHstP2MQglaUmmk9zlHTJqO51ckYmHpYiGmUv6vJL/O5CfDiRbpZX@GuCeBdU3i8AQ).

---

The 10 was `ḤBL65_ɓ>-×`

Here is another 10 byte solution, which I like since it says it is "BOSS"...

```
BoṠS»-~%65
```

[Test-suite here](https://tio.run/##ddA9akJBEAfwfk4hhHT7YL52PtpcwVIsbUSwTpMiTa6RA@QCwS45SbzIuuQh6tO3zcD@mD8zs93sdq@tvez/vj@XP4fh7dlq@/04vn@1toKByuLBe1ogDMks4oxiUdW9BkYZ6V68/HcRqBFZGFIou4QnykgMxKzZPzJMe5cm0UgCieiUyT1NsddyHoMQtKLUTOtxjpp2MZpavRgDUw8LMY1yu5pcmU9NgB9epJv1FWZNAGdNYX0C)

...`BoṠS63r0¤i`, `BoṠS63ŻṚ¤i`, or `BoṠS64ḶṚ¤i` would also work.

---

Another 10 byter (from Dennis) is `æ»64ḶṚ¤Äċ0` (again `æ»63r0¤Äċ0` and `æ»63ŻṚ¤Äċ0` will also work)

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##ddA7TgNBDAbg3qeIlHYi@TV@lEmdGyBERYNyAVoaaiouQJkDpF8p90guMhmxQgvLZhpL88m/bL88Hw6vrV1OX7u91afhc3v@aMP79e3Y2gNsqKwW3nqFsElmEWcUi6ruNTDKSP/Fy3cXgRqRhSGFskt4oozEQMya/SPDtHdpEo0kkIhOmdzTFHstP2MQglaUmmk9zlHTJqO51ckYmHpYiGmUv6vJL/O5CfDiRbpZX@GuCeBdU3i8AQ)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I thought to myself "there must be a golfier way to multiply by isNonNegative" and didn't think of the `Ƒ` quick at all, very nice work!

Comment: Actually, I've been theorizing about `AƑ` for quite some while now. Be warned that it doesn't vectorize! ;-) It's actually "flatten and then check if all elements are nonnegative".

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, 51 bytes

```powershell
param([long]$n)for(;$n-shl$i++-gt0){}($i,65)[!$n]-1
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param([long]$n)for(;$n-shl$i++-gt0){}($i,65)[!$n]-1

}

@(
    ,(-1                   ,0 )
    ,(-9223372036854775808 ,0 )
    ,(9223372036854775807  ,1 )
    ,(4611686018427387903  ,2 )
    ,(1224979098644774911  ,3 )
    ,(9007199254740992     ,10)
    ,(4503599627370496     ,11)
    ,(4503599627370495     ,12)
    ,(2147483648           ,32)
    ,(2147483647           ,33)
    ,(2                    ,62)
    ,(1                    ,63)
    ,(0                    ,64)
) | % {
    $n,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $n
    "$($result-eq$expected): $result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: 0
True: 0
True: 1
True: 2
True: 3
True: 10
True: 11
True: 12
True: 32
True: 33
True: 62
True: 63
True: 64
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 38 bytes

```java
int f(long n){return n<0?0:f(n-~n)+1;}
```

Input as `long` (64-bit integer), output as `int` (32-bit integer).

Port of [*@l4m2*'s C (gcc) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177291/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fZFNTsMwEIX3PcWoK0dRqvFP/EORuACsukQsQptULqlTJU4lVIUlB@CIXCSYEAksECtr5vl9Hr85FOciO@yexm1ddB3cFdZdFgCdL7zdwmidh4rUjduDSy5t6fvWgbvGG7yqiMteXJLS9TAGx6l/rINjNp4bu4NjgJGNb63b3z9AkXyCAXzZeZLR22T9ozSMca4YcqlzoVSuUUcXfusq0oWkVGqJVAumuFYGeaRTxoQJXaOlCH5haDyAQVTUGBbgAsMZw3PkuTEykBUKI/8T80hkNPA0l0L/3Y4/Eb8aD4hf1bD4Xs6U8SRO@7FzvpvnzpfHVdP71SlE72tHbLqE99c3WKYVsckMGsYP)

**Explanation:**

```java
 int f(long n){       // Recursive method with long parameter and integer return-type
   return n<0?        //  If the input is negative:
           0          //   Return 0
          :           //  Else:
           f(n-~n)    //   Do a recursive call with n+n+1
                  +1  //   And add 1
```

---

EDIT: Can be **26 bytes** by using the builtin `Long::numberOfLeadingZeros` as displayed in [*@lukeg*'s Java 8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177304/52210).

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 34 bytes

```
+/×\0=(0>n),(63⍴2)⊤((2*63)××n)+n←⎕
```

Explanation:

```
n←⎕ Prompts for input of number as integer

((2*63)××n) If n is negative add 2 to power 63

(63⍴2)⊤ Convert to 63 bit binary

(0>n), Concatinate 1 to front of binary vector if n negative, 0 if positive

+/×\0= Identify zeros, isolate first contiguous group and sum if first element is zero
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 42 bytes

```cs
x=>x!=0?64-Convert.ToString(x,2).Length:64
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVA9T8MwFJzxr3C3RHIif8UfLSkDElO3IjEghsoyqaXiSLapghC/PTgNAQRveffu3t1wJlYmuvHu1ZvrU@875HzaQgNbOA7tdli1@Ebw6rb3ZxtSfd/vU3C@KwZEy3pnfZeOa8HHDQCT@fEJJhuTDTH73yuCQKUpZUxSzIRquJSNwgrBrwH/RQkXFXBBiFACE8WpZEpqzCAChFKuM9ZK8GzhmhD4KxBjSbSmOY3jvCcSTVkNZo3WIgdJzLWY@b90s7xTkv2KCa7mXPTDyPmEi0C@Ef7ILTz3wR7MsTgfwqWKCJ1fOinB1f4to5c61xn7k60fgkt257wtTHH5LsvN@Ak)

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 31 bytes

```cs
int c(long x)=>x<0?0:c(x-~x)+1;
```

Even shorter, based off of  [@l4m2's C (gcc) answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177291/52210)
Never knew that you could declare functions like that, thanks @Dana!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZA/T8QwDMVn8ik8tqI92UmaP1cOBlY2BgbEcIoCRLpLpaZCRQi@ekmvFBB48fN79m@wS7VLYZpCHMAVhy4@wVjuLscLvMKtK8b6YyzPqZ0Ym7P7Bxh8GnyfYAdvNVWstpwLoTkKZRqpdWPQVPBV7H@oYU2ZVETKKCQjuRZGWxRQMeJc2qytUTKfSEsEv4CImqzlmSYx99msZlaDorFWZZBGadXi/7WbdZ1TvjdCSbNwqx9HLyOsAX0rfG8Ze@x6v3fPxcu@P70iQYjrT0p2dvua1XFz3cXUHfzmrg@DvwnRF644bZdlO30C)

Comment: I think this is valid? https://tio.run/##ZZA/T8QwDMVn8ik8tqI92UmaP1cOBlY2BgbEcIoCRLpLpaZCRQi@ekmvFBB48fN79m@wS7VLYZpCHMAVhy4@wVjuLscLvMKtK8b6YyzPqZ0Ym7P7Bxh8GnyfYAdvNVWstpwLoTkKZRqpdWPQVPBV7H@oYU2ZVETKKCQjuRZGWxRQMeJc2qytUTKfSEsEv4CImqzlmSYx99msZlaDorFWZZBGadXi/7WbdZ1TvjdCSbNwqx9HLyOsAX0rfG8Ze@x6v3fPxcu@P70iQYjrT0p2dvua1XFz3cXUHfzmrg@DvwnRF644bZdlO30C

Answer (score 2):

## Swift (on a 64-bit platform), 41 bytes

Declares a closure called `f` which accepts and returns an `Int`.   This solution only works correctly 64-bit platforms, where `Int` is `typealias`ed to `Int64`.  (On a 32-bit platform, `Int64` can be used explicitly for the closure’s parameter type, adding 2 bytes.)

```
let f:(Int)->Int={$0.leadingZeroBitCount}
```

In Swift, even the fundamental integer type is an ordinary object declared in the standard library.  This means `Int` can have methods and properties, such as [`leadingZeroBitCount`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2884587-leadingzerobitcount) (which is required on all types conforming to the standard library’s [`FixedWidthInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger) protocol).

Comment: interesting. reminds me of Rust. i think it should count as 20 bytes, .leadingZeroBitCount

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 37 bytes

```perl
sub{sprintf("%064b",@_)=~/^0*/;$+[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZPrTsJAEIX/71NMNouhUmH20r1Yq7yHFyJSCJFLpSWRGH11XAoKkSYY4PxpMzv55szpNktno2g5XrB@sszn3Y88mw0nRb9Oa6hVl4btTpB8tZ7wshWzxj0@fi7j8QLaRZoXyfg5g/s8Gw2L1kPeaD2GN7cx6U9n9fI4@CDgNV7U2TBkaZC0WSfelIANkgvW9yfBurSeCpQ26yyF9M033FF6TSfTAmjQpNNX3zScZPPiGmoiyiGB0iBA@p6lL0XaW9V7AINp2dF7mNBwNXc1OmSDmHwurzjsC39e@IkiV04IKY1AqW2kjIks2h08niayTzee@rvGqe6V5lxbjdwqYaQ1DiWA@MWfyCdcCOU81FmtvHvluLcut3gs8zka7xANd074ZBT65ybyLX6j474CURHKyDntkzGonN5cmD38cfy/@GiNF/v4owIigvtUrNTK7tx7WYWv0qGVtnizi5f/xONB9xU/Lej/uj@0G@GVeHkWPHKClXh1Hjx@Aw)

Or this 46 bytes if the "stringification" is not allowed: sub z

```perl
sub{my$i=0;$_[0]>>64-$_?last:$i++for 1..64;$i}
```

Comment: `s/length$&/$+[0]/` (-3 bytes) ;)

Comment: IMO, you're not allowed to remove the `sub` keyword from answers containing Perl 5 functions.

Comment: I've seen whats similar to removing `sub` in answers for other languages, perl6, powershell and more.

Comment: In Perl6, I think you don't need `sub{}` to make a (anonymous?) sub, which explain why it's omitted from Perl6 answers. I agree with @nwellnhof that you shouldn't be allowed to remove `sub`. (when I was still active, like a year ago or so, that was the rule)

Comment: changed now. And included `$+[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 24 bytes

```hs
f n|n<0=0
f n=1+f(2*n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY2xDsIwDET3foXHllJkO2niVOQDGPgCxJCBioo2qqAj/x6idGQ5n9@ddM/weT3mOaUR4jee0WOVnad2rPkQW2rSEqYIHpawXqFe31PcTmNTAdygo3yO0DlmpSyjMtJra3tBKcE/t4VrQ2TEIIlmq8Q6VIUTs3b5c2J07mtH@4ApynunKA7DJW7Z3tMP)

This is basically the same as Kevin Cruijssen's Java solution, but I found it independently.

The argument should have type `Int` for a 64-bit build, or `Int64` for anything.

### Explanation

If the argument is negative, the result is immediately 0. Otherwise, we shift left, *filling in with ones*, until we reach a negative number. That filling lets us avoid a special case for 0.

Just for reference, here's the obvious/efficient way:

## 34 bytes

```hs
import Data.Bits
countLeadingZeros
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 103 bytes

Uses the same *"builtin"* as ceilingcat's answer.

```
f::!Int->Int
f _=code {
instruction 243
instruction 72
instruction 15
instruction 189
instruction 192
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3P83KStEzr0TXDkhwpSnE2ybnp6QqVHNl5hWXFJUml2Tm5ykYmRij8M2NULiGpqhcC0tUvqURV@3/4JLEohIFW4U0BYP/AA)

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 58 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$0=64
$i=until(\e=(2^63>>e)bitand i<>0)inc 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4xLxcDWzIRLJdO2NK8kM0cjJtVWwyjOzNjOLlUzKbMkMS9FIdPGzkAzMy9ZweB/cEkiUKetgoqCgQIc/P@XnJaTmF78X9fT579LZV5ibmZyMQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
în»╧3(∞┼⌠g
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8c6eafcf3328ecc5f467&i=-1%0A-9223372036854775808%0A9223372036854775807%0A4611686018427387903%0A1224979098644774911%0A9007199254740992%0A4503599627370496%0A4503599627370495%0A2147483648%0A2147483647%0A2%0A1%0A0&a=1&m=2)

It's a port of Kevin's 05AB1E solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 41 bytes

The formula for positive numbers is just `63-Floor@Log2@#&`.  Replacement rules are used for the special cases of zero and negative input.

The input need not be a 64-bit signed integer.  This will effectively take the floor of the input to turn it into an integer.  If you input a number outside of the normal bounds for a 64-bit integer, it will tell return a negative number indicating how many more bits would be needed to store this integer.

```
63-Floor@Log2[#/.{_?(#<0&):>2^63,0:>.5}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9NawJBEER/jCARerW/pnvaROMppxxyFyOLrImgWXDnJv72zZwSSE5VPOod6tKWz@7SltOhHUs3lEM7dMPq1hA0wSzijGI5qXvKmOE/c1AjsmxIWdkle6AAMWvUFtm07jSIIBCdIriKijVBE0qKsGo5athfkICpbrOY5t/qwECA98fjajRpXs59f9289h@8nSzmt/3zw@QJp7Plmt9NAJfrebrvpuPb9fRVtsfF5ufkbvwG)

@LegionMammal978's solution is quite a bit shorter at 28 bytes.  The input must be an integer.  Per the documentation: "`BitLength[n]` is effectively an efficient version of `Floor[Log[2,n]]+1`. "  It automatically handles the case of zero correctly reporting `0` rather than `-∞`.

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 28 bytes

```
Boole[#>=0](64-BitLength@#)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@7asNAEEU/xhAcGOGZ2dl5YBSM6xTujQth1pbAD4i2C/l2ZasEkupeDvcU9z7UsdyHOp2HpZa5noe5zP1nR9AFc0rGmNSzmGVHh//MQJRIXZFc2JJbYAJilmgtXKXtJIggEI0iuImCLUEyphyhzTKU0L8gA1PbelLx32rAQIBf20u/7J/PWzmu3no8rVW6/VTfy@Nax93q9WU5fEyPerxsdj@/Tss3)

Comment: `Boole[#>=0](64-BitLength@#)&` is a good bit shorter at 28 bytes. It uses the same basic concept as yours, but applies `BitLength` and `Boole`.

Comment: I totally forgot about BitLength!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 42 bytes

```perl
1while$_>0&&2**++$a-1<$_;$_=0|$_>=0&&64-$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rdPNaoQwEAfwe54i0LCHXSwz@Q7WvkGfQTxYarEqftAe@uxNQ7tdpQouunOJGPgx83ds8rZU3uP7S1HmLH2Ew4Efj6cTyyJ8YGnM0gQ@w/skXGgZsczHLEsgpnf5R9H1HX0dup4@1y19G8q@aMqc9m2Rd7SoaF3ltB0qHyGdF/w94M4ikeNcCMNBaKukMcqCnfCwr8hcN0G9jLG3e6kRtdWAVnIjrHEgKOUXfqdPkHPpAuqslqF76TC0LkYefvLZzDsAg87xkIyEcJ4jH/lzbfsKRCoQyjkdkjEgnT4vzIzf5v/n1S/P5/ymgAjHkIoVWtrJ3oslfqnWRhp5M@XFlTysLiYRhC/8uFRfO8HafAQXeXETHpDAIi9vw8NX3fRFXXU@elL3YRofNeU3)

Longer than a bitstring based solution, but a decent math based solution.

Comment: [Doesn't really work](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tagRiXezkBNzcxEVyMnP10lXttQUx/IUDD6/9/4X35BSWZ@XvF/3QIA) if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @Dada I see that there are a few cases where the floating point division doesn't quite work out properly.  I put in an `int` call that should solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I failed my copy-past it would seem. [This](https://tio.run/##rdO/asMwEAbwXU/hIUNCMb1/OumGPkvoEErAxKYNWdq@elXRurGpBQ52vsWaftx9krvDa@NT2uyf4ONweW7eVerj6bzdNu3LZv@Au8d8qGj3mVKN1TTwd8CVcbURMQcC1uglBB8hjnhYFzfVQ1ava6ydXhRRowJGocAxGHBV0ZVf6TskEsuoRZU8vRjm0Xng4aefxbwBBDSj3IxA/vaVD3yfZbfgxAN7M83NBBDT/sFM@GX@f97/8jTlFxXkCHMrkVXi6N1ziS9lbqWBD2Oeb@RhdvrCT1vprdPP7eawyPNdeEAHRV7uw3@13fnYnt5S3TXf) is what I wanted to send ;)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 15 chars, 30 bytes

```
{¯1+1⍳⍨⍵⊤⍨64⍴2}
```

test for few numbers for see how to use:

```
  f←{¯1+1⍳⍨⍵⊤⍨64⍴2}
  f ¯9223372036854775808
0
  f 9223372036854775807
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 18 bytes

```
i64::leading_zeros
```

[Try it online!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=71da8c48aa4f1edd0fb85db20d7281d4)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 12 bytes

```
+/&\~(64#2)\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxljstqAlEMhvfzFEJFlCLN7eQy51E0oJuB0kJBXCjiPHvPmZ24Cv+X5Eum8fNrc5y3Kh+0Ow7DdXysD/f5Mk6rWz39/dTtaTp//9ZbvdfLLp/D9bDHhF6CiNkIWL2IWXHwpfHOLbFxUUR1BXQhY7cATmociSRaCldp8xKIyd0DYBhBTSLQamK3SwEuEdoUBhKaiO+0JHYzYVt1VvHkl2zJ/QKlLg+k9gSp8g/x20FX)

`(64#2)\` encode the argument as 64 bits

`~` bitwise not

`&\` cumulative boolean and

`+/` sum

Comment: `# = length` ... looks string based

Comment: @Titus `2\ ` gives a list of integers and `#` finds its length. no strings are involved here.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>50</s> 46 bytes

```php
for(;0<$n=&$argn;$n>>=1)$i++;echo$n<0?0:64-$i;
```

Run as pipe with `-R` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d03c08accfe0eaa3e19c42efec9c7bca8b40ae6),

`<?=$argn<0?0:0|64-log($argn+1,2);` has rounding issues; so I took the long way.

Answer (score 1):

bitNumber - math.ceil (math.log(number) / math.log(2))

e.g
64 bit 
NUMBER : 9223372036854775807
math.ceil (math.log(9223372036854775807) / math.log(2)) 
ANS:  63

Comment: If you could add the language name to this, that would be great,as people are likely to down vote answers that don't have the language name included

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
Ｉ⁻⁶⁴Ｌ↨﹪ＮＸ²¦⁶⁴¦²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzczr7RYw8xER8EnNS@9JEPDKbE4VcM3P6U0J1/DM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU0chIL8cyDDSUTAz0QRyjTTBwPr/f4P/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    Ｌ           Length of
       Ｎ        Input as a number
      ﹪         Modulo
         ²      Literal 2
        Ｘ       To the power
           ⁶⁴   Literal 64
     ↨          Converted to base
              ² Literal 2
 ⁻              Subtracted from
  ⁶⁴            Literal 64
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

The `¦`s serve to separate adjacent integer literals. Conveniently, Charcoal's arbitrary numeric base conversion converts `0` into an empty list, however for negative numbers it simply inverts the sign of each digit, so the number is converted to the equivalent unsigned 64-bit integer first.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 49 bytes (broken)

I misread the problem, check back later for a new solution

```
n->{int i=0;while(n%10==0){n/=10;i++;}return i;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcwxD8IgFATgvb/iLSaQppWqG8HRzcnROGCF@ip9NUA1puG3V2Kc7oa7r9cvXfW3x/Kcrg5baJ0OAY4aCeYCKRpvdWvgMOcOlrmROiAuU/Hfh6hjjteINxjyi52iR@rOF9C@CzwjB7CgYKFq/zNQCfm@ozOMVo1QSvCZ1qoREstSJm/i5AlQJrmcPiGaoR6nWD@zGR0xW1vWbLY7IQTnskhp@QI)
I opted for a loop-based solution instead of [recursion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177303/84303) or [built-ins](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/177271/find-the-number-of-leading-zeroes-in-a-64-bit-integer/177304#177304).

Comment: This doesn't work for some of the test cases, for example it returns `0` for `2` and `2147483647`. But if it did work, something you could golf is to replace the `while` loop with `for(;n%10==0;i++)n/=10;` to save 3 bytes

Comment: I didn't realize I was counting zeros of the *binary* form of the number. Mega oof

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 36 bytes (9 instructions)

Hexdump (jelly code page):

```
00000000: e3ff4080 e6ff1020 e5ff0408 e4ff0102  ẉ”@⁰ȧ”Ñ ẓ”¥®ỵ”¢£
00000010: dc0000ff dc00ff00 27ff0001 da00ff00  ṇ¡¡”ṇ¡”¡'”¡¢ḷ¡”¡
00000020: f8010000                             ẏ¢¡¡
```

Disassembled:

```
clz SETL  $255,#4080
    INCML $255,#1020
    INCMH $255,#0408
    INCH  $255,#0102
    MOR   $0,$0,$255    // reverse byte order of input
    MOR   $0,$255,$0    // reverse bit order of input within bytes
    SUBU  $255,$0,1     // y = x - 1
    SADD  $0,$255,$0    // x = popcnt(y & ~x)
    POP   1,0           // return x
```

```