# Calculate the truncated log2 of some unsigned integer

Tags: code-golf, bitwise

## Definition

Given some number, *x* calculate the smallest number *i* such that 2<sup>*i*</sup>≥*x*. This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104785/in-how-many-bits-do-i-fit). It is slightly different in that an input of 16 should yield an output of 4 whereas 16 returns 5 in the linked question.

## Input

Input will be an unsigned 32-bit integer.

## Output

Output will be an unsigned integer (8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit etc. are all ok)

## Test Cases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 15 | 4 |
| 16 | 4 |
| 65536 | 16 |

## Example (C# 51 bytes)

```
uint A(uint x) => (uint)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log2(x));
```

This is code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins! Standard loopholes and rules apply. Tie goes to first poster.

Comment: This question is off-topic because We use C# or any language?  I recommend to post [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to iron out bugs.

Comment: any language. There are no bugs in my example??

Comment: Output will be an unsigned integer (8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit etc. are all ok). while the Input says Input will be an unsigned 32-bit integer.

Comment: Does your example work with x=0 or x=3 or x=15? And I'd say it is still a duplicate because the only difference is that the input is offset by 1.

Comment: Sorry yall I didn't know about the Sandbox. I would delete and re-post but there is already an answer so I wont delete. In the mean time I will fix my example

Comment: @Bubbler I specifically linked that question. This question is slightly different. Please read

Comment: I read it and I already said it doesn't make any significant difference. And also similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35177/78410)

Comment: @Bubbler yea the second one is effectively the same question, but limited to C. To say that the difference is insignificant is just false. Run a unit test for this question on any of the answers from the first question you linked and you will find that the unit test fails.

Comment: On this site, duplicate-ness does not depend on exact equality of tasks. Instead, if many of the existing answers on challenge A can be trivially modified to get answers on challenge B, B is considered a dupe of A. In this case, A is the linked challenge, B is yours, and the trivial modification is subtracting the input by 1. Your unit test argument simply doesn't work on this site. Also, the second link I gave you is now open to all languages.

Comment: Noted. For now, maybe let people have fun answering the question?

Comment: @NigelBess Sorry, we can't really make an exception for this challenge, no matter how good it is. People can always have fun answering the linked question. Perhaps if you post a draft in the Sandbox, people could suggest how to modify your challenge to make it more interesting than the one it's a duplicate of.

Comment: Fair enough. I marked as dupe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
≬E?≥ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiaxFP+KJpeG5hSIsIiIsIjE1Il0=)

Quite literally returns the first number where 2**n >= input

Comment: I just got a tie in 05ab1e at 5 bytes: `2.nî`

Comment: @NigelBess An equal-bytes 05AB1E answer similar as the Vyxal program could be [`∞.Δo‹`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8vXNT8h817Pz/39AUAA). :) Although, as noted by _Bubbler_, simply `<bg` would be a trivial 3-byter based on the challenge that was marked as duplicate. EDIT: And your `2.nî` is 4 bytes, not 5.. Did you accidentally counted the bytes in UTF-8 instead of 05AB1E encoding?

Comment: Yea I counted in UTF-8. What is the normal way to count the bytes?

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
ＩＬ↨⌈⟦⁰⊖Ｎ⟧²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcHBCkBAEADQX3GcLQrl5IaLQu5yGGtC2aXdWfn74T29o9MXniKjOyxDjZ6hI7vxDhV6gh7fwwQDUxpHDWlHhizTCq29Aw/BLORAqVnFUa5@pUhWSPKcHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
       Ｎ    Input as a number
      ⊖     Decremented
     ⁰      Literal `0`
    ⟦   ⟧   List of the above
   ⌈        Maximum
  ↨         Convert to base
         ²  Literal `2`
 Ｌ          Length
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Charcoal converts `0` to `[]` so giving the correct log for an input of `1`, but `0` as input needs to be special-cased.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 23 bytes

```
n->if(n,#binary(n-1),0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYoxCoAwDEWvEurSQAqt0m56EXGoQyUgIRQXT1/j8B/vwdfaOVw6GqxDwsbNC00nS@2vl5CQIo6qeltB2EA7y2Pq/nBgb0SCPRIkgtmYbYWg5LyUA8cH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 26 bytes

```
.+
$*
^((1+)(?=\2))*1*
$#1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLK05Dw1BbU8PeNsZIU1PLUItLRdnw/38DLkMuIy5DUy5DMy4zU1NjMwA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert the input to unary.

```
^((1+)(?=\2))*1*
```

Divide by two as many times as possible, rounding up each time, until `1` is reached. (The leading `^` and trailing `*` are needed to handle the edge case of zero input.)

```
$#1
```

Output the number of rounded divisions made.